# JQuery: How to call RESIZE event only once it's FINISHED resizing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

*How do I call a function once the browser windows has FINISHED resizing?*

I'm trying to do it like so, but am having problems. I'm using the JQuery Resize event function:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  ... // how to call only once the browser has FINISHED resizing?
});
```

However, this function is called *continuously* if the user is manually resizing the browser window. Which means, it might call this function dozens of times in short interval of time.

How can I call the resize function only *a single time* (once the browser window has finished resizing)?

**UPDATE**

Also without having to use a global variable.

Comment: @BGerrissen, if you can show me how to do http://jsfiddle.net/Zevan/c9UE5/1/ without a global variable, I definitely will :)

Comment: the above cleartimeout/settimeout method works wonderfully well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript/JQuery: $(window).resize how to fire AFTER the resize is completed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854407/javascript-jquery-window-resize-how-to-fire-after-the-resize-is-completed)

Answer (score 129, accepted):

[Here is an example using thejh's instructions](http://jsfiddle.net/Zevan/c9UE5/1/)

You can store a reference id to any setInterval or setTimeout. Like this:

```
var loop = setInterval(func, 30);

// some time later clear the interval
clearInterval(loop);
```

Comment: I love that this code is so simply. Any way to make this work **without** having to use a global variable?

Comment: If I see how to do this without the global variable, I'll make that the "accepted answer"

Comment: no problem. There are a few ways. I've edited the answer to reflect the simplest one I could think of.

Comment: thanks for the update but it appears to still use a global variable. Can you update it to not require a global variable (var id). Thanks

Comment: I think you missed the link at the end of the post... check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/Zevan/c9UE5/5/

Comment: Thanks for this. Too bad you have to do a horrible hack like this just to make sure resize runs once. Why would a browser make it run twice?

Comment: just an fyi, id is now a 'global' as it is in the 'window scope' ('this' inside a resize event is 'window')

try this instead:

  http://jsfiddle.net/5KpYs/2/
  ​

Comment: @AlexFord An application might need to know the current size as soon as possible, maybe to prevent the window from getting to big, or any number of other scenarios...

Comment: Extremely intelligent

Comment: If you do it with a debounce/timeout and hold the resize in place (i.e. not triggering the resize event) for more than your debounce delay then it thinks you have finished and fires. I think I need to check the state of mouse button instead of using a debounce :(

Comment: This is simply ingenious! Thanks @Zevan

Comment: For some reason, this doesn't completely get rid of the problem for me in FF. Every time I resize, it fires the function an extra time. I have it as `jQuery( window ).resize function() { ... }).trigger( 'resize' );` and on load, the function fires once. After I resize a bunch, the function will fire twice. If I resize again, the function fires 3 times, etc. It has reduced the amount of firing significantly, but I was expecting it to only fire once.

Answer (score 89):

[Debounce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debounce#Contact_bounce).

```
function debouncer( func , timeout ) {
   var timeoutID , timeout = timeout || 200;
   return function () {
      var scope = this , args = arguments;
      clearTimeout( timeoutID );
      timeoutID = setTimeout( function () {
          func.apply( scope , Array.prototype.slice.call( args ) );
      } , timeout );
   }
}


$( window ).resize( debouncer( function ( e ) {
    // do stuff 
} ) );
```

Note, you can use this method for anything you want to debounce (key events etc).

Tweak the timeout parameter for optimal desired effect.

Comment: I just tried running this and it appears to run **TWICE**. I replaced *"// do stuff"* with *"$("body").append("<br/>DONE!");"* and it calls it TWICE on a browser resize

Comment: oops... I forgot a rather important part (actually setting the timeoutID)... Fixed now, please do try again ;)

Comment: Why is the debouncer calling .resize twice? Am I doing something wrong? Live example seen here -->  http://jsfiddle.net/c9UE5/3/

Comment: Works now :)  (A lot more code than I was hoping for but it does work).

Comment: What does **func.apply(scope ,Array.prototype.slice.call(args));** do?

Comment: @user43493: It calls the cuntion `func`, with the internal `this` pointer pointing to `scope`, and with `Array.prototype.slice.call(args)` (which generates a standard array out of `args`) as the arguments

Comment: Why does this code seem so much more complicated than http://jsfiddle.net/Zevan/c9UE5/1/  I do like that no global variable is being used but it still seems way more complicated than the code I linked too.

Comment: This is a reusable abstraction, so you don't have to handcode timeouts or keep track of global timeoutID's yourself. You can use it for way more then just window resizing ;) for example to debounce a submit button by passing a higher timeout parameter. You can opt for the less code solution, but I do advice you keep this snippet in your kit, you will appreciate it later on ;)

Comment: Make sense. Can you show the less code solution (that's more specific to this one particular use case)?

Comment: You linked that yourself.. http://jsfiddle.net/Zevan/c9UE5/1/ but you have to handcode that each time yourself for anything you want to debounce and then keep track of global variables so that your timeout ID doesn't get overwritten.

Comment: Can you show me how to do http://jsfiddle.net/Zevan/c9UE5/1/ without having to use a global variable?

Comment: I'll make the simplified, no global variable response as my "accepted answer" :)

Comment: Underscore.js has a nice implementation of this if you're already using that lib. http://underscorejs.org/#debounce

Comment: why you did not keep a reference to the prototype.slice in closure too? 
it's small performance improvement, but anyway.. 
http://jsfiddle.net/8zpKt/

Comment: @Denis There's is no performance improvement in that, it would actually be a performance reduction (storing a needless reference). If you use .slice a lot in your code, it might be worthwhile to store a reference to reduce byte size, but it's still slower (insignificantly though) than calling it directly from the Array prototype.

Comment: My new _most loved_  ;> for years was struggling with clear interval...

Answer (score 22):

You can use `setTimeout()` and `clearTimeout()` in conjunction with [`jQuery.data`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/):

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    clearTimeout($.data(this, 'resizeTimer'));
    $.data(this, 'resizeTimer', setTimeout(function() {
        //do something
        alert("Haven't resized in 200ms!");
    }, 200));
});
```

**Update**

I wrote an *extension* to enhance jQuery's default `on` (& `bind`)-event-handler. It attaches an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements if the event was not triggered for a given interval. This is useful if you want to fire a callback only after a delay, like the resize event, or else.
https://github.com/yckart/jquery.unevent.js

```
;(function ($) {
    var methods = { on: $.fn.on, bind: $.fn.bind };
    $.each(methods, function(k){
        $.fn[k] = function () {
            var args = [].slice.call(arguments),
                delay = args.pop(),
                fn = args.pop(),
                timer;

            args.push(function () {
                var self = this,
                    arg = arguments;
                clearTimeout(timer);
                timer = setTimeout(function(){
                    fn.apply(self, [].slice.call(arg));
                }, delay);
            });

            return methods[k].apply(this, isNaN(delay) ? arguments : args);
        };
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Use it like any other `on` or `bind`-event handler, except that you can pass an extra parameter as a last:

```
$(window).on('resize', function(e) {
    console.log(e.type + '-event was 200ms not triggered');
}, 200);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ARTsinn/EqqHx/

Comment: Literally do the same google search every day. and come to the same page for this piece of code. Wish i could just remember it haha.

Answer (score 7):

```
var lightbox_resize = false;
$(window).resize(function() {
    console.log(true);
    if (lightbox_resize)
        clearTimeout(lightbox_resize);
    lightbox_resize = setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('resize');
    }, 500);
});
```

Comment: I like this the most but why not use curly brackets on your conditional statements? I know it works without them but it's a pain for other devs to look at ;)

Answer (score 7):

Just to add to the above, it is common to get unwanted resize events because of scroll bars popping in and out, here is some code to avoid that:

```
function registerResize(f) {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        clearTimeout(this.resizeTimeout);
        this.resizeTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
            var oldOverflow = document.body.style.overflow;
            document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
            var currHeight = $(window).height(),
                currWidth = $(window).width();
            document.body.style.overflow = oldOverflow;

            var prevUndefined = (typeof this.prevHeight === 'undefined' || typeof this.prevWidth === 'undefined');
            if (prevUndefined || this.prevHeight !== currHeight || this.prevWidth !== currWidth) {
                //console.log('Window size ' + (prevUndefined ? '' : this.prevHeight + "," + this.prevWidth) + " -> " + currHeight + "," + currWidth);
                this.prevHeight = currHeight;
                this.prevWidth = currWidth;

                f(currHeight, currWidth);
            }
        }, 200);
    });
    $(window).resize(); // initialize
}

registerResize(function(height, width) {
    // this will be called only once per resize regardless of scrollbars changes
});
```

see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/azLkzkae/)

Answer (score 5):

[Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) has a couple of great methods for this task: [`throttle`](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle) and [`debounce`](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce). Even if you're not using Underscore, take a look at the source of these functions. Here's an example:

```
var redraw = function() {'redraw logic here'};
var debouncedRedraw = _.debounce(redraw, 750);
$(window).on('resize', debouncedRedraw);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is my approach:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    var tos = {};
    var idi = 0;
    var fn  = function(id)
    {
        var len = Object.keys(tos).length;

        if(len == 0)
            return;

        to = tos[id];
        delete tos[id];

        if(len-1 == 0)
            console.log('Resize finished trigger');
    };

    window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
        idi++;
        var id = 'id-'+idi;
        tos[id] = window.setTimeout(function(){fn(id)}, 500);
    });
});
```

The resize-event-listener catches all incoming resize calls, creates a timeout-function for each and saves the timeout-identifier along with an iterating number prepended by `'id-'` (to be usable as array key) in the `tos`-array.

each time, the timout triggers, it calls the `fn`-function, that checks, if that was the last timeout in the `tos` array (the fn-function deletes every executed timout). if true (= `if(len-1 == 0)`), the resizing is finished.

Comment: It would be nice if you had some comments or an explanation as to what you're doing here

Answer (score 1):

jQuery provides an `off` method to remove event handler

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if(magic == true) {
        $(window).off('resize', arguments.callee);
    }
});
```