# jquery bind getting invoked more than once

Tags: jquery, bind

Plain jQuery binding function is getting called twice for me, I have seen this problem when working with jQuery mobile also.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(window).bind("resize",function(){

$("#length").text($(window).width());
$("#length").show("slow");
$("#length").hide("slow");
});
});


 <html>
   <body>
     <div id='length' style= display:none></div>
     <div class="font size">1</div>
   </body>
 </html>
```

fiddled : http://jsfiddle.net/2Yy7Q/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well known browsers behaviour, a possible workaround:

http://jsfiddle.net/2Yy7Q/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    (function () {
        var timeout;
        $(window).bind("resize", function () {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(function () {
                $("#length").text($(window).width());
                $("#length").show("slow");
                $("#length").hide("slow");
            }, 50);
        });

    })();
});
```

**NOTE**  you could set timeout duration to 0, 50 is to give you the idea

Comment: Here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5534363/why-does-the-jquery-resize-event-fire-twice