# window.onresize fires twice

Tags: javascript

I'm new to js. Please, don't kick painfully.
I have this code

```
    window.onresize=function() {alert(1);};
```

When I resize any browser`s window, this function fires twice. Why? And how  to rewrite this code that code will fire once.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: I think we're gonna need some more info and a jsfiddle perhaps.

Comment: see this answer => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5534363/why-does-the-jquery-resize-event-fire-twice

Comment: It does not fire twice, it fires every time the browser thinks a new resize is triggered. You need to use a timeout to make this work in an acceptable way.

Comment: thanks all, I'm sorry for noob question!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need a timeout to bundle the resize events.

```
var res;
window.onresize=function() {
    if (res){clearTimeout(res)};
    res = setTimeout(function(){console.log("resize triggered");},100);
};
```

[live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/uFmAe/1/)

Comment: `100` is too long. A user can fire two legitimate resize events. You could even argue that any timeout is too long. In theory you could programatically resize the window to generate events with arbitrary intervals.

Comment: @Halcyon I think, you misunderstood the question. The goal is to supress all subsequent resize events (which however still belong to the same resize). It heavily depends on the scenario, but given a normal event of a user resizing his browser in a normal way, one could argue, whether 100ms is perhaps too low, but certainly not too much.

Comment: My point is that debouncing using a timeout is at least a little bit inaccurate. In my opinion the better way to debounce is checking the dimension of the window. If the dimension doesn't change you can safely discard the resize event. The timeout is good, but there is a better way.

Comment: Sorry, but I disagree - your approach means a huge computational overhead which might not be feasible when working with a lot of resizing events. Also, it's concept does not seem to work - If the dimension does not change, it also won't emit a resize event (after all, that's the whole point of this event...)! On the other hand, most browser emit A LOT of resize events (if you're resizing slowly basically for every pixel), which would not get caught by your solution. This however is exactly OP wanted to circumvent. But I'm willing to change my mind, if you provide a working code snippet.

Comment: Maybe there is something you're not aware of. There is a bug (or feature) where browsers fire the resize event _twice_ (probably a resize-start and resize-end). So the resize events always fire in pairs, even if there was only one resize action by the user. I interpret OPs question as pertaining to that. The duplicate event warrants a debounce. The aim of the debounce is not to rate-limit resize events, it's to catch the duplicates - and only the duplicates. Rate limiting in this case also serves as a debounce, but a lossy one.

Comment: As for the claim that checking the viewport dimension is _"a huge computational overhead"_. I don't think this claim holds (depending on your definition of _huge_), but if you want to you could make a benchmark. I'm checking `window.innerWidth/Height`, to my knowledge there is no additional computation required. If you cache `window` in a local variable (as you should) I doubt the check overhead will amount to much.

Comment: I guess you are referring to a Chrome Bug ~ 4 years ago, which fired the resize event twice. In that case (where it is infact a duplicate), your solution would have worked. However, it does not handle the general case of browsers firing multiple resize events on one user action (not clicking e.g. the maximize button, but dragging the window). Imo, using timeouts is a more generic solution.

Answer (score 6):

This event will fire multiple times in different browsers (some once you've finished the the resize, others during).

One way to get around this is to wait a certain amount of time (say half a second) after the event fires, to see if there are further updates. If not, you can proceed with the alert.

e.g.

```
var resizeTimer;
window.onresize = function(){
    if (resizeTimer){
        clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
    } 
    resizeTimer = setTimeout(function(){
        alert(1);
        }, 500);
};
```

See it work on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pYxgq/).

Comment: Well, since our answers are exactly equal I really had to disagree on that ^.^

Comment: Same as Christoph's answer, `500` is too long.

Answer (score 2):

To prevent function from "firing" the same result more than once when user resize

```
var doc = document; //Access the dom only once
var currentWidth = doc.body.clientWidth;
var newWidth = currentWidth; //If you want to "fire" at startup, change to: var newWidth = 0
window.onresize = function (){
    newWidth = doc.body.clientWidth;
    if(currentWidth != newWidth){
        currentWidth = newWidth;

        //Fire the results     
        console.log("clientWidth:", currentWidth);
     };
};
```

Comment: This is the proper way to detect the duplicate resize event. Either the first or second event will not actually modify the viewport. Perpahs `window.clientWidth/Height` is better than `document.body.clientWidth`.

Comment: @Halcyon You are misunderstanding the concept of resize events and/or the asynchonous nature of Javascript. This approach will not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I propose other solution because I don't like the timeouts,

```
   `var resized;
    window.onresize = function () {
        if(resized){
            resized = false;
        }
        else{
            resized = true;
            alert('resize');
        }
    };`
```

Comment: This assumes there are exactly two events. If there is only one event, or more than two events, this code will inaccurately block events.