# Why does my JavaScript onresize fire twice?

Tags: javascript

I have a fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/fJMe9/

```
window.onresize = function (e) {
    console.log("Page resized");
};
```

And every time I resize the window I get two logs to the console

Comment: What about this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5534363/why-does-the-jquery-resize-event-fire-twice

Comment: Seems that Chrome and IE log twice, firefox log once.

Answer (score 3):

It's a well known bug (perhaps relating to event bubbling? I say well known, but that's other people who know it, not me :P ). Use a `setTimeout` to check the last time the window was resized to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
window.onresize = function (e) {
    console.log(e);
};
```

you'll see the event fires every time you drag the browser window

Depends on implementation: maybe 2 times, the first for tell you the window is being resized and the second for windows finished resizing.