# Window Resize issue in jQuery when I resize window one time, it gives me 2

Tags: jquery

When I run this one time it gives me window resized :2 why this so and how can get 1 when i resize window only one time.

```
<script src="jquery-2.2.1.min.js">

</script>
<script>

var x=0;
$(document).ready(function()
{
           $(window).resize(function()
           {
               $("span").text(x += 1);
           });        
});    
</script>
</head>    
<body>
<p>Window resized :<span></span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why it triggers twice**

This answers your question: [Why does the jQuery resize event fire twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8355701/3165725)

I added a fiddle that confirms it triggers twice on scale down in chrome, once on scale up.In Edge it triggers once on both scale up and down.

```
var x=0;

$(window).resize(function()
{
  console.log(x +=1);
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/1361/)

**How to make it trigger once**

```
var x = 0,
    y = 0;
$(window).resize(function() {
    clearTimeout(y);
    y = setTimeout(finishedRezise, 100);
});

function finishedRezise(){
  console.log(x += 1);  
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/1363/)

The javascript function SetTimeout() prevents the function from being executed by a specified number of milliseconds. clearTimeout() clears the timer from SetTimout() and takes the returned value from setTimeout() as parameter, and it needs to be defined globally. See W3Schools documentation [W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp)

Comment: actully its working fine in google chrome, but not in firefox. Anyway thanx

Comment: Updated my answer with fix that I tested working in Firefox, Chrome and Edge

Comment: yes now its working in all browsers but could you explain me what you did in this code, I can not understand this why you took x, y,clearTimeout and all