# Fire resize event once not based on timing

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Is it possible to avoid twice firing events by browsers, but not based on timing (in case your resize event execution lasts long that solution is bad)

Comment: Could you be more specific? Are you thinking of [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/)?

Comment: Chrome for example firest some events (resize) twice. Timeout based solution works, but when my resize funtion execution lasts for 10sec's  and then it begins to execute again its terrible... So, I cant set short timeout, and when I set long timeout it would block real resize event when user would indeed resize window after 5s for example. I need to force one event function firing per event. In Mozilla its ok, in Chrome it's twice.

Comment: Can't really be done! You could have hacked it by detecting mouse button down etc. but those events don't register on the browser chrome, only the window, so no banana. Timers are the only viable option.

Comment: Right, you can't control the events, but you can control how YOU handle them. Timers are the answer.

Comment: So at least - why is that? Why Chrome fires it twice? Times are the answer only when you control how long events execution lasts. When you dont know it, becouse you got for example some complicated drawing - it gets tricky. And its terrible when all the drawing is done twice - and you need to redraw it every resize, but once only.

Comment: The resize event fires continuosly ?

Comment: It really would be nice to have an event like `onafterresize`, but this is not implemented by any browser (yet). Unfortenately our only change for the moment is to use a delay to achieve this.

Comment: @Teemu You could just write it yourself. [http://jsfiddle.net/NSmsE/](http://jsfiddle.net/NSmsE/). All credit where credit is due to [BGerrissen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298612/jquery-how-to-call-resize-event-only-once-its-finished-resizing)

Comment: @OPOPO Timers are pretty much the best option. I mean, you could detect for Chrome and have a toggle lock, so it runs every other time, but this seems like a bad idea.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I can't see anything in the console when running your fiddle : (. Just a moment, I'll try it locally...

Comment: I will try to add some timeout 'blocker' on the end of resize function. Will let you know.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I've just tested your fiddle code locally, it really seems to work. This is a nice catch, and upvoted Zevan's answer... thought it still uses delays I've mentioned in my previous comment ; ).

Comment: A fix to previous, upvoted BGerrissen ofcourse...

Comment: You can modify James Padolsey's approach to fit your needs: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/special-scroll-events-for-jquery/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.blockResize = false;
$(window).resize(function() {

    if (window.blockResize) return;

        //do stuff


    window.blockResize = true;
    setTimeout(function(){window.blockResize = false},200);


});
```

Ok, it's still based on timers, but It works in my case now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeout()` and `clearTimeout()` in conjunction with [`jQuery.data`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/):

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    clearTimeout($.data(this, 'resizeTimer'));
    $.data(this, 'resizeTimer', setTimeout(function() {
        //do something
        alert("Haven't resized in 200ms!");
    }, 200));
});
```

**Update**

I wrote an *extension* to enhance jQuery's default `on` (& `bind`)-event-handler. It attaches an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements if the event was not triggered for a given interval. This is useful if you want to fire a callback only after a delay, like the resize event, or else.
https://github.com/yckart/jquery.unevent.js

```
;(function ($) {
    var methods = { on: $.fn.on, bind: $.fn.bind };
    $.each(methods, function(k){
        $.fn[k] = function () {
            var args = [].slice.call(arguments),
                delay = args.pop(),
                fn = args.pop(),
                timer;

            args.push(function () {
                var self = this,
                    arg = arguments;
                clearTimeout(timer);
                timer = setTimeout(function(){
                    fn.apply(self, [].slice.call(arg));
                }, delay);
            });

            return methods[k].apply(this, isNaN(delay) ? arguments : args);
        };
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Use it like any other `on` or `bind`-event handler, except that you can pass an extra parameter as a last:

```
$(window).on('resize', function(e) {
    console.log(e.type + '-event was 200ms not triggered');
}, 200);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ARTsinn/EqqHx/