# HTML element not resizing when I set window.onresize

Tags: javascript, web

I recently started learning about web development, in particular Javascript, and I'm trying to write some simple functions to advance my grasp of the language. 
I wrote a function to resize a box's height to be proportional to the window, but for some reason it isn't working - the resize function is not updating the page each time I resize the browser window. I feel like I'm making some really silly error, but because I'm not familiar with Javascript I can't figure out what it is.

My HTML is extremely simple:

```
<body>
<div id = "box">Hi.</div>
</body>
```

and the Javascript code is:

```
function resizeToScreen(element, percent)
{
    var wHeight = window.innerHeight;
    var objHeight = wHeight * (percent/100);
    element.style.height = objHeight +"px";
}

window.onresize = resizeToScreen(document.getElementById('box'), 50);
```

Here's the link to the jsFiddle, which highlights the box yellow:
http://jsfiddle.net/sallyg/mb8hB/1/

Comment: You seem to be immediately executing the `resizeToScreen` function. You need to provide a function reference to `onresize`, so that it can be called when the window is resized. Like: `window.onresize = function () { resizeToScreen(document.getElementById("box"), 50); };`. You want to bind the event **after** the DOM is ready (putting it inside of `window.onload = function () { /* HERE */ };` should be fine for now), so that resizing doesn't occur before the `#box` element is ready

Comment: @Ian this. I was just about to write that up but you beat me to the punch!

Comment: Why don't you use simple CSS for the `div`: `height: 50%;`

Comment: @Teemu Yeah, I had a feeling this could probably be done without JavaScript, but I didn't look into the question enough, and just answered the immediate problem. If that would work, you should definitely post an answer

Comment: @Ian I don't know, OP clearly asks why the code doesn't work. You've answered to the question, maybe just add the CSS thing to your answer...

Comment: @Teemu I just thought you should get the credit for pointing it out :) So as I look at it more, I'm realizing simply `height: 50%;` wouldn't work, because the div's height is only as big as its container. So if the body doesn't have an explicit height, I'm not sure the `50%` would do much/anything. If the body's height was set to `100%`, then I think the `50%` would work properly

Comment: @Ian Well, someone might downvote kind of a irrelevant answer. But true, `height` wouldn't work without setting a height to the body too.

Comment: Hi @Teemu, I did already know you could use the height:50% property, but my main purpose in writing this code was to practice this in Javascript since I'm trying to learn it. Thank you for pointing that out, though - it's definitely a lot simpler.

Comment: @user2506848 That's what I was thinking... Anyway, are you aware, that `onresize` will fire hundreds of times during a resize. That'll make even a simple code quite expensive. Please check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4298672/1169519), it might be useful...

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be immediately executing the `resizeToScreen` function. You need to provide a function reference to `onresize`, so that it can be called later when the `window` is resized. Like:

```
window.onresize = function () {
    resizeToScreen(document.getElementById("box"), 50);
};
```

You want to bind the event after the DOM is ready, like putting it inside of:

```
window.onload = function () {
    // HERE
};
```

should be fine for now, so that resizing doesn't occur before the `#box` element is ready.

Note that instead of setting `.onEVENT` properties is fine, but can be overwritten, so it's somewhat suggested to use `addEventListener` (and `attachEvent` for old IE).

Here's an example of that, which can hopefully seamlessly be used in both types of browsers:

```
function addEvent(element, eventName, callback) {
    if (element.addEventListener) {
        element.addEventListener(eventName, callback, false);
    } else if (element.attachEvent) {
        element.attachEvent("on" + eventName, callback);
    }
}
```

and use it like:

```
addEvent(window, "load", function () {
    addEvent(window, "resize", function () {
        resizeToScreen(document.getElementById("box"), 50);
    });
});
```

References:

- `addEventListener`: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/DOM/elemento.addEventListener
- `addEventListener` vs. `onEVENT`: [addEventListener vs onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick)

Comment: How old is old IE?
BTW Great answer this is the reason I use SO.

Comment: Thank you :) Well, I'm not sure if there's a defined "old IE", but I've always taken it as meaning older than version 9

Comment: @raam86 Not sure if you were notified of that comment - I forgot to add the `@raam86` part :)

Comment: Thanks a lot @ian, that was very helpful and it now works. Just out of curiosity though, what did you mean about onevent properties getting overwritten?

Comment: @user2506848 No problem, glad it helps :) What I meant about that is it's possible to overwrite properties. So say you wanted to set `window.onload` multiple times (or maybe another library attempts to). Every time you set it, it gets overwritten. Say you have `window.onload = function () { alert("1"); }` and then later, in whatever place, there is also this code: `window.onload = function () { alert("2"); }`. Well, when the window loads, only the `2` will be alerted. Using the `addEventListener` allows you to attach multiple listeners for an event without overwriting

Comment: @user2506848 And I just updated my answer with a new link in the "References" part that explains that a little more

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the below statement. You are "***calling***" `resizeToScreen()`, and "***assigning***" its return value to "onresize".

```
window.onresize = resizeToScreen(document.getElementById("box"), 50);
```

Instead, you want to "***attach***" your function to the resize event. This is how you do it:

```
window.onresize = function () {
    resizeToScreen(document.getElementById("box"), 50);
};.
```

Comment: Thanks @tushar-roy! This helped me a lot in understanding the fundamental problem with my code.