# why javascript files are loading twice console.log and alert and jquery "click" is running twice

Tags: javascript

why javascript files are loading twice twice?

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $(function() {
    console.log('hi');


    });
});
```

this is the console output:
[image]

both the vm and the Categories are the same file

the problem is not just with the console.log, any function that i call like jquery "click" is triggered twice!

scrollingPage.js:

```
/**
 * fullPage 1.3.1
 * https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js
 * MIT licensed
 *
 * Copyright (C) 2013 alvarotrigo.com - A project by Alvaro Trigo
     */

(function($) {

$('.PageData').live('mouseleave' ,function(){
    window.windowScrollOF = false;
});

$('.PageData').live('mouseenter', function(){
    window.windowScrollOF = true;
});

$('.CatData').live('mouseleave' ,function(){
    window.windowScrollOF = false;
});

$('.CatData').live('mouseenter', function(){
    window.windowScrollOF = true;
});

$.fn.fullpage = function(options) {
    // Create some defaults, extending them with any options that were provided
    options = $.extend({
        "verticalCentered" : true,
        'resize' : true,
        'slidesColor' : [],
        'anchors':[],
        'scrollingSpeed': 1200,
        'easing': 'easeInQuart',
        'menu': false,
        'navigation': false,
        'navigationPosition': 'right',
        'navigationColor': '#000',
        'controlArrowColor': '#fff',
        'loopBottom': false,
        'loopTop': false,
        'loopHorizontal': false,
        'autoScrolling': true,
        'scrollOverflow': false,
        'css3': false,
        'paddingTop': null,
        'paddingBottom': null,
        'fixedElements': null,

        //events
        'afterLoad': null,
        'onLeave': null,
        'afterRender': null,
        'afterSlideLoad': null
    }, options);        

    //Defines the delay to take place before being able to scroll to the next section
    //BE CAREFUL! Not recommened to change it under 400 for a good behavior in laptops and 
    //Apple devices (laptops, mouses...)
    var scrollDelay = 50;

    $.fn.fullpage.setAutoScrolling = function(value){
        options.autoScrolling = value;

        var element = $('.section.active');

        if(options.autoScrolling){
            $('html, body').css({
                'overflow' : 'hidden',
                'height' : '100%'
            });

            if(element.length){
                //moving the container up
                if(options.css3){
                    var translate3d = 'translate3d(0px, -' + element.position().top + 'px, 0px)';
                    transformContainer(translate3d, false)
                }else{
                    //deleting the possible negative top
                    $('#superContainer').css('top', '-'  + element.position().top + 'px');
                }
            }

        }else{
            $('html, body').css({
                'overflow' : 'auto',
                'height' : 'auto'
            });

            if(options.css3){
                //moving the container up
                var translate3d = 'translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)';
                transformContainer(translate3d, false)
            }else{
                //deleting the possible negative top
                $('#superContainer').css('top', '0px');
            }

            //scrolling the page to the section with no animation
            $('html, body').scrollTop(element.position().top);
        }

    };


    //flag to avoid very fast sliding for landscape sliders
    var slideMoving = false;

    var isTablet = navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry|Windows Phone)/);

    var windowsHeight = $(window).height();
    var isMoving = false;
    var lastScrolledDestiny;

    addScrollEvent();

    $('body').wrapInner('<div id="superContainer" />');

    //creating the navigation dots 
    if (options.navigation) {
        $('body').append('<div id="fullPage-nav"><ul></ul></div>');
        var nav = $('#fullPage-nav');

        nav.css('color', options.navigationColor);


        if (options.navigationPosition === 'right') {
            nav.css('right', '17px');
        } else {
            nav.css('left', '17px');
        }
    }

    $('.section').each(function(index){
        var slides = $(this).find('.slide');
        var numSlides = slides.length;

        if(!index){
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }

        $(this).css('height', windowsHeight + 'px');

        if(options.paddingTop && options.paddingBottom){
            $(this).css('padding', options.paddingTop  + ' 0 ' + options.paddingBottom + ' 0');
        }

        if (typeof options.slidesColor[index] !==  'undefined') {
            $(this).css('background-color', options.slidesColor[index]);
        }

        if (typeof options.anchors[index] !== 'undefined') {
            $(this).attr('data-anchor', options.anchors[index]);
        }


        if (options.navigation) {
            var link = '';
            if(options.anchors.length){
                link = options.anchors[index];
            }
            nav.find('ul').append('<li><a href="#' + link + '"><span></span></a></li>');
        }

        // if there's any slide
        if (numSlides > 0) {
            var sliderWidth = numSlides * 100;
            var slideWidth = 100 / numSlides;

            slides.wrapAll('<div class="slidesContainer" />');
            slides.parent().wrap('<div class="slides" />');

            $(this).find('.slidesContainer').css('width', sliderWidth + '%');
            $(this).find('.slides').after('<div class="controlArrow prev"></div><div class="controlArrow next"></div>');
            $(this).find('.controlArrow.next').css('border-color', +options.controlArrowColor);
            $(this).find('.controlArrow.prev').css('border-color', + options.controlArrowColor);

            if(!options.loopHorizontal){
                $(this).find('.controlArrow.prev').show();
            }


            slides.each(function(index) {
                if(!index){
                    $(this).addClass('active');
                }

                $(this).css('width', slideWidth + '%');

                if(options.verticalCentered){
                    addTableClass($(this));
                }
            });
        }else{
            if(options.verticalCentered){
                addTableClass($(this));
                $(this).addClass('active');
            }
        }




    }).promise().done(function(){           
        $.fn.fullpage.setAutoScrolling(options.autoScrolling);

        $.isFunction( options.afterRender ) && options.afterRender.call( this);

        //fixed elements need to be moved out of the plugin container due to problems with CSS3.
        if(options.fixedElements && options.css3){
            $(options.fixedElements).appendTo('body');
        }

        //vertical centered of the navigation + first bullet active
        if(options.navigation){
            nav.css('margin-top', '-' + (nav.height()/2) + 'px');
            nav.find('li').first().find('a').addClass('active');
        }

        //moving the menu outside the main container (avoid problems with fixed positions when using CSS3 tranforms)
        if(options.menu && options.css3){
            $(options.menu).appendTo('body');
        }

        if(options.scrollOverflow){
            //after DOM and images are loaded 
            $(window).on('load', function() {
                $('.section').each(function(){
                    var slides = $(this).find('.slide');

                    if(slides.length){
                        slides.each(function(){
                            createSlimScrolling($(this));
                        });
                    }else{
                        createSlimScrolling($(this));
                    }

                });
            });
        }

        $(window).on('load', function() {
            scrollToAnchor();   
        });

    });

    var scrollId;
    var isScrolling = false;

    //when scrolling...
    $(window).scroll(function(e){

        if(!options.autoScrolling){                 
            var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();

            var scrolledSections = $('.section').map(function(){
                if ($(this).offset().top < (currentScroll + 100)){
                    return $(this);
                }
            });

            //geting the last one, the current one on the screen
            var currentSection = scrolledSections[scrolledSections.length-1];

            //executing only once the first time we reach the section
            if(!currentSection.hasClass('active')){
                isScrolling = true; 

                var yMovement = getYmovement(currentSection);

                $('.section.active').removeClass('active');
                currentSection.addClass('active');

                var anchorLink  = currentSection.data('anchor');
                $.isFunction( options.onLeave ) && options.onLeave.call( this, currentSection.index('.section'), yMovement);

                $.isFunction( options.afterLoad ) && options.afterLoad.call( this, anchorLink, (currentSection.index('.section') + 1));

                activateMenuElement(anchorLink);    
                activateNavDots(anchorLink, 0);


                if(options.anchors.length && !isMoving){
                    //needed to enter in hashChange event when using the menu with anchor links
                    lastScrolledDestiny = anchorLink;

                    location.hash = anchorLink;
                }

                //small timeout in order to avoid entering in hashChange event when scrolling is not finished yet
                clearTimeout(scrollId);
                scrollId = setTimeout(function(){                   
                    isScrolling = false;
                }, 100);
            }

        }                   
    }); 




    var touchStartY = 0;
    var touchStartX = 0;
    var touchEndY = 0;
    var touchEndX = 0;

    /* Detecting touch events 

    * As we are changing the top property of the page on scrolling, we can not use the traditional way to detect it.
    * This way, the touchstart and the touch moves shows an small difference between them which is the
    * used one to determine the direction.
    */
    $(document).on('touchmove', function(event){

        if(options.autoScrolling && isTablet){
            //preventing the easing on iOS devices
            event.preventDefault();
            var e = event.originalEvent;
            var touchMoved = false;

            if (!isMoving) { //if theres any #

                touchEndY = e.touches[0].pageY;
                touchEndX = e.touches[0].pageX;


                //if movement in the X axys is bigger than in the Y and the currect section has slides...
                if($('.section.active').find('.slides').length && Math.abs(touchStartX - touchEndX) > Math.abs(touchStartY - touchEndY) ){
                    if(touchStartX > touchEndX){
                        $('.section.active').find('.controlArrow.next').trigger('click');
                    }
                    else if(touchStartX < touchEndX){
                        $('.section.active').find('.controlArrow.prev').trigger('click');
                    }
                }
                //vertical scrolling
                else{
                    var scrollable = $('.section.active').find('.scrollable');
                    if(touchStartY > touchEndY){
                        if(scrollable.length > 0 ){
                            //is the scrollbar at the end of the scroll?
                            if(isScrolled('bottom', scrollable)){
                                $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideDown();

                            }else{
                                return true;
                            }
                        }else{
                            // moved down
                            $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideDown();
                        }
                    } else {

                        if(scrollable.length > 0){
                            //is the scrollbar at the start of the scroll?
                            if(isScrolled('top', scrollable)){
                                $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideUp();
                            }
                            else{
                                return true;
                            }
                        }else{
                            // moved up
                            $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideUp();
                        }
                    }
                }                   
            }
        }
    });

    $(document).on('touchstart', function(event){
        if(options.autoScrolling && isTablet){
            var e = event.originalEvent;
            touchStartY = e.touches[0].pageY;
            touchStartX = e.touches[0].pageX;
        }
    });



    /**
     * Detecting mousewheel scrolling
     * 
     * http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/mouse-wheel/index.html
     * http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-javascript-mouse-wheel/
     */
    function MouseWheelHandler(e) {
        if(window.windowScrollOF){
                return;
        }
        if(options.autoScrolling){
            // cross-browser wheel delta
            e = window.event || e;
            var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1,
                    (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));
            var scrollable;
            var activeSection = $('.section.active');

            if (!isMoving) { //if theres any #

                //if there are landscape slides, we check if the 

scrolling bar is in the current one or not
                    if(activeSection.find('.slides').length){
// MAKE THE PAGE SCROLL ON MOUSE
//                       scrollable= activeSection.find('.slide.active').find('.scrollable');
                    }else{
//                      scr

ollable = activeSection.find('.scrollable');
                }

                //scrolling down?
                if (delta < 0) {
                    if(scrollable.length > 0 ){
                        //is the scrollbar at the end of the scroll?
                        if(isScrolled('bottom', scrollable)){
                            $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideDown();
                        }else{
                            return true; //normal scroll
                        }
                    }else{
                        $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideDown();
                    }
                }

                //scrolling up?
                else {
                    if(scrollable.length > 0){
                        //is the scrollbar at the start of the scroll?
                        if(isScrolled('top', scrollable)){
                            $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideUp();
                        }else{
                            return true; //normal scroll
                        }
                    }else{
                        $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideUp();
                    }
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    }


    function addScrollEvent(){
        if (document.addEventListener) {
            document.addEventListener("mousewheel", MouseWheelHandler, false); //IE9, Chrome, Safari, Oper
            document.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", MouseWheelHandler, false); //Firefox
        } else {
            document.attachEvent("onmousewheel", MouseWheelHandler); //IE 6/7/8
        }
    }

    $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideUp = function(){
        var prev = $('.section.active').prev('.section');

        //looping to the bottom if there's no more sections above
        if(options.loopTop && !prev.length){
            prev = $('.section').last();
        }

        if (prev.length > 0 || (!prev.length && options.loopTop)){
            scrollPage(prev);
        }
    };

    $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideDown = function (){
        var next = $('.section.active').next('.section');

        //looping to the top if there's no more sections below
        if(options.loopBottom && !next.length){
            next = $('.section').first();
        }

        if (next.length > 0 || (!next.length && options.loopBottom)){
            scrollPage(next);
        }
    };

    $.fn.fullpage.moveToSlide = function (index){
        var destiny = '';

        if(isNaN(index)){
            destiny = $('[data-anchor="'+index+'"]');
        }else{
            destiny = $('.section').eq( (index -1) );
        }

        if (destiny.length > 0) {
            scrollPage(destiny);
        }
    };

    function scrollPage(element, callback) {
        var scrollOptions = {}, scrolledElement;
        var dest = element.position();
        var dtop = dest !== null ? dest.top : null;
        var yMovement = getYmovement(element);
        var anchorLink  = element.data('anchor');
        var sectionIndex = element.index('.section');
        var leavingSection = sectionIndex;

        element.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

        //preventing from activating the MouseWheelHandler event
        //more than once if the page is scrolling
        isMoving = true;

        if(!$.isFunction( callback )){
            if(typeof anchorLink !== 'undefined'){
                location.hash = anchorLink;
            }else{
                location.hash = '';
            }
        }

        if(options.autoScrolling){
            scrollOptions['top'] = -dtop;
            scrolledElement = '#superContainer';
        }else{
            scrollOptions['scrollTop'] = dtop;
            scrolledElement = 'html, body';
        }

        //calculating the index of the section we are leaving
        if(yMovement === 'up'){
            leavingSection +=2; 
        }           

        if(options.css3 && options.autoScrolling){


            $.isFunction( options.onLeave ) && options.onLeave.call( this, leavingSection, yMovement);

            var translate3d = 'translate3d(0px, -' + dtop + 'px, 0px)';
            transformContainer(translate3d, true);

            setTimeout(function(){
                $.isFunction( options.afterLoad ) && options.afterLoad.call( this, anchorLink, (sectionIndex + 1));

                    setTimeout(function(){
                        isMoving = false;
                        $.isFunction( callback ) && callback.call( this);
                    }, scrollDelay);
            }, options.scrollingSpeed);
        }else{
            $.isFunction( options.onLeave ) && options.onLeave.call( this, leavingSection, yMovement);

            $(scrolledElement).animate(
                scrollOptions 
            , options.scrollingSpeed, options.easing, function() {
                //callback
                $.isFunction( options.afterLoad ) && options.afterLoad.call( this, anchorLink, (sectionIndex + 1));

                setTimeout(function(){
                    isMoving = false;
                    $.isFunction( callback ) && callback.call( this);
                }, scrollDelay);
            });
        }

        //flag to avoid callingn `scrollPage()` twice in case of using anchor links
        lastScrolledDestiny = anchorLink;

        //avoid firing it twice (as it does also on scroll)
        if(options.autoScrolling){
            activateMenuElement(anchorLink);
            activateNavDots(anchorLink, sectionIndex);
        }
    }

    function scrollToAnchor(){
        //getting the anchor link in the URL and deleting the `#`
        var value =  window.location.hash.replace('#', '').split('/');
        var section = value[0];
        var slide = value[1];

        if(section){  //if theres any # 
            scrollPageAndSlide(section, slide);
        }
    }


    //detecting any change on the URL to scroll to the given anchor link
    //(a way to detect back history button as we play with the hashes on the URL)
    $(window).on('hashchange',function(){
        if(!isScrolling){
            var value =  window.location.hash.replace('#', '').split('/');
            var section = value[0];
            var slide = value[1];
            slide  = typeof slide == 'undefined' ? 0 : slide ;

            /*in order to call scrollpage() only once for each destination at a time
            It is called twice for each scroll otherwise, as in case of using anchorlinks `hashChange` 
            event is fired on every scroll too.*/
            if (section !== lastScrolledDestiny) {
                scrollPageAndSlide(section, slide);
            } else {
                if(window.ontimeTagTrigger == false){
                    scrollPageAndSlide(section, slide);
                    window.ontimeTagTrigger = true;
                } else {
                    window.ontimeTagTrigger = false;
                }
            }
        }
    });



    /**
     * Sliding with arrow keys, both, vertical and horizontal
     */
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {

        //Moving the mian page with the keyboard arrows
        if (!isMoving) {
            switch (e.which) {
            //up
            case 38:
            case 33:
                $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideUp();
                break;

            //down
            case 40:
            case 34:
                $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideDown();
                break;

            //left
            case 37:
                $('.section.active').find('.controlArrow.prev').trigger('click');

                break;

            //right
            case 39:
                $('.section.active').find('.controlArrow.next').trigger('click');
                break;

            default:
                return; // exit this handler for other keys
            }
        }
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#fullPage-nav a', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var index = $(this).parent().index();
        scrollPage($('.section').eq(index));


    });

    /**
     * Scrolling horizontally when clicking on the slider controls.
     */
    $('.section').on('click', '.controlArrow', function() {

        //not that fast my friend! :)
        if (slideMoving) {
            return;
        }
        slideMoving = true;

        var slides = $(this).closest('.section').find('.slides');
        var currentSlide = slides.find('.slide.active');
        var destiny = null;

        currentSlide.removeClass('active');

        if ($(this).hasClass('prev')) {
            destiny = currentSlide.prev('.slide');

        } else {
            destiny = currentSlide.next('.slide');
        }

        //is there isn't a next slide in the secuence?
        if(!destiny.length) {
            //to the last
            if ($(this).hasClass('prev')) {
                destiny = currentSlide.siblings(':last');
            } else {
                destiny = currentSlide.siblings(':first');
            }   
        }

        landscapeScroll(slides, destiny);

        destiny.addClass('active');
    });


    /**
     * Scrolling horizontally when clicking on the slider controls.
     */
    $('.section').on('click', '.toSlide', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var slides = $(this).closest('.section').find('.slides');
        var currentSlide = slides.find('.slide.active');
        var destiny = null;

        destiny = slides.find('.slide').eq( ($(this).data('index') -1) );

        if(destiny.length > 0){
            currentSlide.removeClass('active');

            landscapeScroll(slides, destiny);

            destiny.addClass('active');
        }
    });

    /**
    * Scrolls horizontal sliders.
    */
    function landscapeScroll(slides, destiny){
        var destinyPos = destiny.position();
        var slidesContainer = slides.find('.slidesContainer').parent();
        var slideIndex = destiny.index('.slide');
        var section = slides.closest('.section');
        var sectionIndex = section.index('.section');
        var anchorLink = section.data('anchor');

        var slideAnchor = destiny.data('anchor');

        if(typeof slideAnchor === 'undefined'){
            slideAnchor = slideIndex;
        }

        //only changing the URL if the slides are in the current section (not for resize re-adjusting)
        if(section.hasClass('active')){

            if(!options.loopBottom){
                //hidding it for the fist slide, showing for the rest
                section.find('.controlArrow.prev').toggle(slideIndex!=0);
            }

            //isn't it the first slide?
            if(slideIndex){
                location.hash = location.hash.split('/')[0] + '/' + slideAnchor;

                if(!options.loopBottom){
                    //hidding it for the last slide, showing for the rest
                    section.find('.controlArrow.next').toggle(!destiny.is(':last-child'));
                }           
            //first slide
            }else{
                location.hash = location.hash.split('/')[0];
            }
        }

        if(options.css3){
            var translate3d = 'translate3d(-' + destinyPos.left + 'px, 0px, 0px)';

            slides.find('.slidesContainer').addClass('easing').css({
                '-webkit-transform': translate3d,
                '-moz-transform': translate3d,
                '-ms-transform':translate3d,
                'transform': translate3d
            });
            setTimeout(function(){
                $.isFunction( options.afterSlideLoad ) && options.afterSlideLoad.call( this, anchorLink, (sectionIndex + 1), slideAnchor, slideIndex );

                slideMoving = false;
            }, options.scrollingSpeed);
        }else{
            slidesContainer.animate({
                scrollLeft : destinyPos.left
            }, options.scrollingSpeed, function() {

                $.isFunction( options.afterSlideLoad ) && options.afterSlideLoad.call( this, anchorLink, (sectionIndex + 1), slideAnchor, slideIndex);

                //letting them slide again
                slideMoving = false; 
            });
        }
    }


    if (!isTablet) {
        var resizeId;

        //when resizing the site, we adjust the heights of the sections
        $(window).resize(function() {
            //in order to call the functions only when the resize is finished
            //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298612/jquery-how-to-call-resize-event-only-once-its-finished-resizing
            clearTimeout(resizeId);
            resizeId = setTimeout(doneResizing, 500);
        });

    }
    $(window).bind('orientationchange', function() {
        doneResizing();
    });

    /**
     * When resizing is finished, we adjust the slides sizes and positions
     */
    function doneResizing() {
        var windowsWidtdh = $(window).width();
        var windowsHeight = $(window).height();

        //text and images resizing
        if (options.resize) {
            resizeMe(windowsHeight, windowsWidtdh);
        }

        $('.section').each(function(){
            var scrollHeight = windowsHeight - parseInt($(this).css('padding-bottom')) - parseInt($(this).css('padding-top'));

            //resizing the scrolling divs
            if(options.scrollOverflow){
                $(this).find('.scrollable').css('height', scrollHeight + 'px').parent().css('height', scrollHeight + 'px');
            }

            //adjusting the height of the table-cell for IE and Firefox
            if(options.verticalCentered){
                $(this).find('.tableCell').css('height', windowsHeight + 'px');
            }

            $(this).css('height', windowsHeight + 'px');

            //adjusting the position fo the FULL WIDTH slides...
            var slides = $(this).find('.slides');
            if (slides.length > 0) {
                landscapeScroll(slides, slides.find('.slide.active'));
            }
        });

        //adjusting the position for the current section
        var destinyPos = $('.section.active').position();

        var activeSection = $('.section.active');

        //isn't it the first section?
        if(activeSection.index('.section')){
            scrollPage(activeSection);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Resizing of the font size depending on the window size as well as some of the images on the site.
     */
    function resizeMe(displayHeight, displayWidth) {
        //Standard height, for which the body font size is correct
        var preferredHeight = 825;
        var windowSize = displayHeight;

        /* Problem to be solved

        if (displayHeight < 825) {
            var percentage = (windowSize * 100) / preferredHeight;
            var newFontSize = percentage.toFixed(2);

            $("img").each(function() {
                var newWidth = ((80 * percentage) / 100).toFixed(2);
                $(this).css("width", newWidth + '%');
            });
        } else {
            $("img").each(function() {
                $(this).css("width", '');
            });
        }*/

        if (displayHeight < 825 || displayWidth < 900) {
            if (displayWidth < 900) {
                windowSize = displayWidth;
                preferredHeight = 900;
            }
            var percentage = (windowSize * 100) / preferredHeight;
            var newFontSize = percentage.toFixed(2);

            $("body").css("font-size", newFontSize + '%');
        } else {
            $("body").css("font-size", '100%');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Activating the website navigation dots according to the given slide name.
     */
    function activateNavDots(name, sectionIndex){
        if(options.navigation){
            $('#fullPage-nav').find('.active').removeClass('active');
            if(name){ 
                $('#fullPage-nav').find('a[href="#' + name + '"]').addClass('active');
            }else{
                $('#fullPage-nav').find('li').eq(sectionIndex).find('a').addClass('active');
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Activating the website main menu elements according to the given slide name.
     */
    function activateMenuElement(name){
        if(options.menu){
            $(options.menu).find('.active').removeClass('active');
            $(options.menu).find('[data-menuanchor="'+name+'"]').addClass('active');
        }
    }

    /**
    * Return a boolean depending on whether the scrollable element is at the end or at the start of the scrolling
    * depending on the given type.
    */
    function isScrolled(type, scrollable){
        if(type === 'top'){
            return !scrollable.scrollTop();
        }else if(type === 'bottom'){
            return scrollable.scrollTop() + scrollable.innerHeight() >= scrollable[0].scrollHeight;
        }
    }

    /**
    * Retuns `up` or `down` depending on the scrolling movement to reach its destination
    * from the current section.
    */
    function getYmovement(destiny){
        var fromIndex = $('.section.active').index('.section');
        var toIndex = destiny.index('.section');

        if(fromIndex > toIndex){
            return 'up';
        }
        return 'down';
    }       


    function createSlimScrolling(element){
        //needed to make `scrollHeight` work under Opera 12
        element.css('overflow', 'hidden');

        //in case element is a slide
        var section = element.closest('.section');

        var contentHeight = element.get(0).scrollHeight  - parseInt(section.css('padding-bottom')) - parseInt(section.css('padding-top'));
        if ( contentHeight > windowsHeight) {
            if(options.verticalCentered){
                element.find('.tableCell').wrapInner('<div class="scrollable" />');
            }else{
                element.wrapInner('<div class="scrollable" />');
            }

            var scrollHeight = windowsHeight - parseInt(section.css('padding-bottom')) - parseInt(section.css('padding-top'));

            element.find('.scrollable').slimScroll({
                height: scrollHeight + 'px',
                size: '10px',
                alwaysVisible: true
            });
        }

        //undo 
        element.css('overflow', '');
    }

    function addTableClass(element){
        element.addClass('table').wrapInner('<div class="tableCell" style="height:' + windowsHeight + 'px;" />');
    }


    /**
    * Adds a css3 transform property to the container class with or without animation depending on the animated param.
    */
    function transformContainer(translate3d, animated){
        $('#superContainer').toggleClass('easing', animated);

        $('#superContainer').css({
            '-webkit-transform': translate3d,
            '-moz-transform': translate3d,
            '-ms-transform':translate3d,
            'transform': translate3d
        });
    }


    /**
    * Scrolls to the given section and slide 
    */
    function scrollPageAndSlide(section, slide){

        var element = $('[data-anchor="'+section+'"]');
                $('.CatBox.visible').removeClass('visible')
                $('.MainCats').fadeOut();
                $('.CloseCatBox').css({
                    visibility: 'hidden'
                });

        scrollPage(element, function(){
            if(typeof slide != 'undefined'){
                var slides = element.find('.slides');
                var destiny =  slides.find('[data-anchor="'+slide+'"]');
                if(!destiny.length){
                    destiny = slides.find('.slide').eq(slide);
                }                   

                slides.find('.slide').first().removeClass('active');

                landscapeScroll(slides, destiny);

                destiny.addClass('active');
            }
        });
    }
};
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Note that it come's from two differnt files

Comment: Try using different browser and see if the it behaves the same. Most likely you have some extension installed and that is somehow interception all these calls.

Comment: same issue on firefox and chrome

Comment: Then, check if you are loading the script twice.

Comment: @ShuhelAhmed it is loaded a second time cause of a bug of jQuery, you can look at my answer to see where and why.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your problem is that `Categories.js` and all other scripts placed in the `body` are loaded two times, once by the `script` tag and another time by jQuery using AJAX.

The reason for that is, that you have  `script` tags in the `body` of your site in combination with the line `118` in `scrollingPage.js`:

```
 $('body').wrapInner('<div id="superContainer" />');
```

[jQuery (prior to 1.9) will load and execute the scripts that are wrapped by the newly created `div`  a second time when you call `wrapInner`](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10470).

**Possible solutions:**

- update to jQuery 1.9+ if possible
- move your scripts from `body` to the head
- remove them from the `body` before the code of `scrollingPage.js` is executed

Comment: thank you for the solution but I am curious what are those vm cache files

Comment: @Waqleh When jQuery requests scripts of the same domain they are loaded using `XMLHttpRequest` (without the use of `script` tags), the server submits the requested script, but the browser would not execute/parse it because it is requested as _data_ by jQuery. Then jQuery tells the browser to evaluate that script. But because jQuery passes the script to the browser as string, the browser has no knowledge what the URL of the script is, and because of that it creates a generic name for the evaluated string.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).load( function() { console.log('hi'); });
```

Comment: This is more correct, but doesn't seem to be the issue. A jQuery DOM ready handler set after the DOM is ready will fire immediately.

Comment: the problem is not just with the console.log, any function that i call like onclick is run twice