# Collecting keypresses and firing a function after a time out

Tags: javascript, jquery, key-bindings

I am building an small CAD app that allows the user to select items and then press LEFT/RIGHT arrow keys to move them.

### **The problem**

The problem is that the function that moves the elements takes too long to process if my canvas has many elements drawn on  it.

The worst is that if the user presses and holds the arrow keys, the function needs to get fired so many times that I get the dreaded *Unresponsive Script* alert from my browser.

Even if the user burst-fires a keypress instead of holding it, I still have a problem.

**So I figured that the way to go, is:**

- Collect keypresses and after e.g 2000ms to fire up the function with
  the appropriate keypressCounter - *the number of keypresses collected
  before keyUp*

**The problem with the method above:**

The user will have to wait for the timeout even if just one keypress was made - which does not have a huge overhead - therefore the ''crude'' method described above is less than ideal. It will make the nudge functionality feel cludgy where it could be fast.

**What would be the most correct way to go around this? Any suggestions are welcome since the solution I suggest above seems rather crude**

### **Notes:**

- I would appreciate code snippets, even rudimentary ones. I'm still in
  my early coding stages. Or at least a comprehensive explanation to
  any proposed solutions.
- I am using Paper.js as the canvas library to draw the items, but that
  shouldn't be a factor in any solution

### **The code this far:**

```
//Keybinding ''right'' arrow key - Fires up the function to nudge left. 

$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.which === 39) {
        nudgeSelection("right");
    }
});



//Function that moves the selected element(s). Accepts direction as parameter.

 function nudgeSelection(direction) {

     var selected = paper.project.selectedItems;

     for (var i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
         switch (direction) {
         case "up":
             selected[i].position.y = selected[i].position.y - 1;

             break;
         case "down":
             selected[i].position.y = selected[i].position.y + 1;

             break;
         case "left":
             selected[i].position.x = selected[i].position.x - 1;

             break;
         case "right":
             selected[i].position.x = selected[i].position.x + 1;

             break;

         }

     }
 }
```

Comment: You could use a [debouncer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4298672/1169519).

Comment: @Teemu So I can get into clubs more easily? JK, checking it out now.

Comment: @Teemu The debouncer works great - but it does not collect the keypresses during the time delay. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: That is the purpose of a debouncer... Probably you should use smaller delay than 2 secs. If you'll collect all the keypresses, your code will stuck anyway when executing them from the query. I'd forget the "extra" keypresses totally.

Comment: @Teemu I figured I could collect the amount of keypresses in the debouncer function and then pass them as a parameter to the nudge() function. Seems like a win-win situation. The debouncer could also act as a ''buffer''