# (window).scrollTop() scroll giving error in Mozilla?

Tags: javascript, jquery

First of all please don't mark it as duplicate question because I have seen all the questions regarding this topic and tried all the solutions but none of them helped me.Here is my JSP page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
            $(window).scroll(function () {
 if ($(window).scrollTop() >= ($(document).height()-250) - ($(window).height())) {
  more_options();
}
});

function more_options() 
{
alert("hii");
}

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    </body>
 </html>
```

I was trying to make facebook like scroll for showing more features as soon as user scrolls to half of the page.The above function

```
  $(window).scroll(function () {
 if ($(window).scrollTop() >= ($(document).height()-250) - ($(window).height())) {
  more_options();
```

is working well in Chrome but when i run this page in Mozilla Firefox it repeatedly calls the more_options function and shows irrelevant output.Actually the more_options function show here is demo with alert int it but actually I am using AJAX in that function and fetching more results from database.Chrome Shows the actual result but Mozilla shows unexpected result and repeat the entries come from AJAX call.

Here is [**Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9agjs9q1/).

Comment: Mousewheel scrolling is implemented a bit differently in Chrome and FF. If you'll drag the scrollbar, both browsers behave the same way. Use `console.log` instead of `alert`, you'll get [the idea](http://jsfiddle.net/vbatg8v6/).

Comment: @Teemu Thanks man if I am dragging then chrome and Mozilla gives the same result but wj=hen i am using mouse scroll then Mozilla doesn't give desired output.Could you provide any solution for Mousewheel scrolling

Comment: You could use a [debouncer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4298672/1169519), or a flag as karan3112 has suggested.

Comment: @Teemu karan3112's solution not working.I will try debouncer though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the smooth scrolling of Mozilla. Use a boolean variable and add that in the condition.

JS:

```
    var flag = true; //Global variable with default value True.
        $(window).scroll(function () {
         if ($(window).scrollTop() >= ($(document).height()-250) - ($(window).height()) && flag == true) {
          more_options();
        }
       });

    function more_options() 
    {
        flag = false;
        alert("hii");
    }
```

Change the value of the flag to `true` after the ajax success event or when needed.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/karan3112/9agjs9q1/2/)

Comment: Sorry mate your solution didn't work when I am using Mousewheel scrolling.If you could add fiddle for the solution.That would be great.