# Activate function on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I want to build a Tumblr-like slider (http://www.tumblr.com/), that when the browser detects a scroll attempt it does something, in my case it'll run a function.

I can use `$(window).scroll(function(){ /* ... */ });`, but it won't work normally (it will be too fast). How can I do that it allows one scroll at a time and then stop it for 2 seconds to let it finish the animation?

Thanks.

Comment: You need a [debouncer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4298672/1169519).

Comment: I believe you are looking for something like [pagePiling.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/pagePiling/)

Answer (score 0):

You can apply your animations after some timeout.

```
var t = 0;

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if(timer==0){timer=1;setTimeout(yourFunc,2000);}
});

function yourFunc(){
    //your animations there
    timer=0;
}
```