# $(".abc").click() is not working on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using one click function() to render some chart on my project.

The code is as below

```
$('.abc').click(function() {
       checkGraph();
});
```

But when i resize the window then this click event is not firing. Means my chart us not getting rendered.

I tried some of the things as below but none worked

**Approach 1**

```
$(document).on('click','.abc',function(){
  checkGraph();
});
```

**Approach 2**

```
var crclick = (function(){
            $('.abc').click(function() {
                checkGraph();
            });
    });
    crclick();
    $(window).resize(function(){
        console.log("Window resized New");
        crclick();
    });
```

In approach 2, i am getting `console` output but click function is not working.

Comment: Why so many down votes here.. pl let me knw reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resize and click events are separate. If you want both to call checkGraph, bind them individually to call `checkGraph()`. If you were binging to events to the same element you could do it in once call.

```
$('.abc').click(function() {
   checkGraph();
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    checkGraph();
});
```

I wouldn't do the `.trigger` method mentioned in other answers, it's not very clear code, with potential other consequences.

Answer (score 0):

use on window resize. You are just binding the click on resize.

```
 $(window).resize(function(){
    checkGraph();
});
```

Comment: I was also, but then not. Weird. Anyway your solution may click a LOT

Comment: Who is downvoted please comment and why ? Let me learn where I am wrong ?

Comment: Yes I know but this is what he want!

Comment: This may is not very clear. Someone who tries to maintain this would have no idea why you're clicking a button on window resize, but a direct call to checkGraph() makes sense. Also `.trigger` could also cause other click events that dont need to fire on resize to fire erroneously.

Answer (score 0):

Why would click fire on a resize? You are only assigning the handler.

Later you can click it using `$(".abc").click();` or `$(".abc").trigger("click");`

Be aware you likely want to only click AFTER a resize

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15170104/295783