# On resize, moving li from nested ul into top level ul is creating lots of lis

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a responsive menu. On the mobile version, I want a ul to display 4 list items. On resize to desktop, 2 list items get appended to a previously unused nested ul. This works fine. However, if I resize back to mobile size, instead of appending the 2 list items back to the top level ul, it seems to create a bunch of lis.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.has-child').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
    $('.has-child ul').toggleClass('clicked');
  });
});

$(window).on('resize', function() {
  if ($(window).width() >= 800) {
    $('.nav-container').detach().appendTo('.header-content');
    $('.has-parent').appendTo('.has-child ul');
  } else {
    $('.nav-container').detach().appendTo('.site');
    $('.has-parent').appendTo('.site-navigation ul');
  }
}).trigger('resize');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav-container">
  <nav class="site-navigation">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="pageone.php">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li id="has-child" class="has-child"><a href="#"><i class="ion-person"></i></a>
        <ul>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="has-parent"><a href="account.php">Account</a>
      </li>
      <li class="has-parent"><a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
      </li>

      <li><a href="logout.php">Login</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="register.php">Register</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Converted to snippet. Your resize function is currently deleting everything from the page.

Comment: To add on to what roger just said, see this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298612/jquery-how-to-call-resize-event-only-once-its-finished-resizing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298612/jquery-how-to-call-resize-event-only-once-its-finished-resizing)

Comment: are you looking only for jquery/native js solution?

Comment: @taburetkin not particularly.

Comment: @db1500 then you should take a look at css media queries. as i can see your task can be done with css without js at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it working how you wanted.

However, I must say this is a somewhat strange way of doing things. Modern frameworks like [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) and [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) provide css utility classes for [showing and hiding](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) menus depending on media queries at play.

In simpler terms, you can have 2 menus and then show or hide either one depending on screen size with `css` only.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.has-child').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
    $('.has-child ul').toggleClass('clicked');
  });
});

$(window).on('resize', function() {
  if ($(window).width() >= 800) {
    $('.nav-container').detach().appendTo('.header-content');
    
    if($('.has-child ul li').length  == 0){
      $('.header-content .has-parent').detach().appendTo('.has-child ul');
    }
  } else {
    $('.nav-container').detach().appendTo('.site');
    
    if($('.site-navigation > ul > .has-parent').length  == 0){
      $('.site .has-parent').detach().appendTo('.site-navigation > ul');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box;}

.header-content, .site{
  float: left;
  width:50%;
  background: gray;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 30px;
}

.site{border-left: 2px solid white;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="header-content">
  <h4>Header Content</h4>

</div>

<div class="site">
 <h4>Site</h4>
  
</div>

<div class="nav-container">
  <nav class="site-navigation">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="pageone.php">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li id="has-child" class="has-child"><a href="#"><i class="ion-person"></i></a>
        <ul>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="has-parent"><a href="account.php">Account</a>
      </li>
      <li class="has-parent"><a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
      </li>

      <li><a href="logout.php">Login</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="register.php">Register</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I had previously done it two separate menus, but decided to experiment.

Answer (score -1):

On resize event fires repeatedly as you change the browser width.  Essentially to fix this problem you would need to have some indicator that the function to append has already fired and to stop firing after completion.