# Google Pie Chart Is Not Responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js, google-visualization

I am trying to make my chart responsive. I have added this code (as below) to make my chart responsive. But still it is not working. Can somebody help me to figure it out ? Thank you.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']}); 
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart); 
   
function drawChart() { 
  var jsonData = $.ajax({ 
      url: "<?php echo base_url() . 'index.php/main/lihat_graph' ?>", 
      dataType: "json", 
      async: false 
      }).responseText; 
       
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

  var options = {
    title:    '',
    hAxis:    {title: 'Jumlah Kepakaran'},
    vAxis:    {title: 'Jumlah Kepakaran'},
    bubble:   {textStyle: { fontName: 'arial', fontSize: 12 }},
    colors:   ['beige','pink','#00ADF9', 'maroon', 'red', 'green', 'purple', 'gray', 'orange']
  };

  if(data.getNumberOfRows() == 0){
    $("#chart_div").append("Graf Bidang Kepakaran masih dalam proses 
    pengumpulan data. Graf akan dipaparkan setelah proses pengumpulan data 
    selesai.")
  }else{
   var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
   chart.draw(data, options);        
  }
} 


$(window).resize(function(){
  drawChart();
});
</script>
```

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lt7d.png) is the image of my graph.

Answer (score 0):

your width is always 800. justify it to window size and do the math to make it nest in your box as you want.

```
width : window.innerWidth,
```

see this link and write a better code. the way you wrote has performance issue. 
[JQuery: How to call RESIZE event only once it's FINISHED resizing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298612/jquery-how-to-call-resize-event-only-once-its-finished-resizing)

Comment: now i adjust my code without width and height set. but i still use the .resize function. i work on my code. but the problem is my graph looks too small,  i am not able to read even the label. you can view my graph here -> http://smkphp.ukm.my/domainexpert/

Comment: now my graph become smaller, not similar as i wanted.

Comment: create a fiddle plz.