# Ember : debounce called multiple times on scroll event listener

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I added a debounce method inside a scroll event listener. Something like this.

```
$group.on("scroll.topFix",() => {
   console.log('scroll event');
   debounce(this, ()=> {
     console.log('debounce called);
   },1000);
});
```

When I do the scroll on `$group` the debounce is also called the same number of times the scroll event called. I don't know where is the loophole in this thing.

For example, if **5 times the scroll event** printed then **debounce called** is also called **5 times**.

This is the link for [ember debounce documentation.](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/release/functions/@ember%2Frunloop/debounce)

Comment: I don't know ember.js, but in general, debouncer is attached to the event, and the actual event handler is passed to the debouncer as an argument.

Comment: Can you explain to me a bit more clarification? I didn't understand your quote.

Comment: Please take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4298672/1169519). It's not an ember.js post, but BGerrissen's answer introduces well the common base of the debouncers. I.e. `$group.on("scroll.topFix", debounce(e => {// event hander here}));`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you pass an anonymous function to `debounce`:

```
debounce(this, ()=> {
  console.log('debounce called);
},1000);
```

this is problematic because you recreate this function *every time when you cann `debounce`*! So you never call `debounce` twice with the same function, which is necessary for it to do anything different from a `setTimeout`.

So you should create/save this function to somewhere and then call it like

```
debounce(this, this.doSomething, 1000);
```

Make sure you always pass *exactly the same function*. Just because 2 functions do the same thing does not mean its the same function instance.

Answer (score 0):

This approach is working for me...

```
$group.on("scroll.topFix",() => {
  console.log('scroll event');
  debounce(this, scrollfunction},1000);
});

let scrollfunction = () => {
   console.log('debounce called);
};
```

When `scroll event` triggers `4` times at the same time `debounce called` is called only one time.

Answer (score -1):

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"></script>
$(window).scroll(function() {
   console.log('scroll event');
   debounce(this, ()=> {
     console.log('debounce called');
   },1000);
})
```

Comment: I think I'm doing the same way you mentioned in your answer. When scroll starts it passes the debounce as a return.

Comment: This is not a debouncer, this just delays a function, and calls it as many times as the scroll handler was called.

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some context around your source-code. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.