# Prevent modal from closing down if there is a keydown event that has been triggered

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I am showing and hiding some modals by altering their CSS properties. I want them to be displayed until there is no key event in last 3 seconds. Is there a way to handle this via JavaScript? VueJs solutions would be better.

I am currently hiding the modal after 3 seconds like this :

```js
   

 function a(){
    document.querySelector("#playPause").style.display = "block";
                  setTimeout(() => {
                    document.querySelector("#playPause").style.display = "none";
                  }, 3000);
    }
```

```css
#playPause{
     display:none;
      background-color:black;
    }
```

```html
<button onclick="a()">Display</button>
<div id="playPause">EXAMPLE</div>
```

Comment: [Debounce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4298672/1169519) a keyup listener ..?

Comment: @Teemu Is there any working example of it?

Comment: edited the post @Teemu. onclick instead of click

Comment: There's an example in the linked post, just attach keyup instead of resize. BGerrissen's code works also with `addEventListener`, just call `debounce` and pass it your listener function instead of passing the function directly.

Comment: @AEB thanks for editing that removing/hiding back. I needed to change 6 characters, so *on*click wasn't enough of a change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the timeout as a variable and clear it before setting it again:

```js
   

var timeout;
function a(){
    clearTimeout (timeout);
    document.querySelector("#playPause").style.display = "block";
    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        document.querySelector("#playPause").style.display = "none";
    }, 3000);
}
```

```css
#playPause{
     display:none;
      background-color:black;
    }
```

```html
<button onclick="a()">Display</button>
<div id="playPause">EXAMPLE</div>
```