# How implement debounce for event listener ? Problem with storage event

Tags: javascript

I have debounce funtion

```
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
  // 'private' variable for instance
  // The returned function will be able to reference this due to closure.
  // Each call to the returned function will share this common timer.
  var timeout;

  // Calling debounce returns a new anonymous function
  return function() {
    // reference the context and args for the setTimeout function
    var context = this,
      args = arguments;

    // Should the function be called now? If immediate is true
    //   and not already in a timeout then the answer is: Yes
    var callNow = immediate && !timeout;

    // This is the basic debounce behaviour where you can call this 
    //   function several times, but it will only execute once 
    //   [before or after imposing a delay]. 
    //   Each time the returned function is called, the timer starts over.
    clearTimeout(timeout);

    // Set the new timeout
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {

      // Inside the timeout function, clear the timeout variable
      // which will let the next execution run when in 'immediate' mode
      timeout = null;

      // Check if the function already ran with the immediate flag
      if (!immediate) {
        // Call the original function with apply
        // apply lets you define the 'this' object as well as the arguments 
        //    (both captured before setTimeout)
        func.apply(context, args);
      }
    }, wait);

    // Immediate mode and no wait timer? Execute the function..
    if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
  }
}
```

and some function for example :

```
const storageEventCb = () => console.error(1); 

// Define the debounced function
var debouncedCb = debounce(storageEventCb, 1500);
debouncedCb(); // run
debouncedCb(); // ignore 
debouncedCb(); // ignore
```

feel good but when I lisnener event storage

```
window.addEventListener('storage', storageEventCb );
```

I get many call function . How to fix ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4298672/1169519

Comment: You did not define `storageEventCb2`

Comment: Can you please provide the code where you are executing this line `window.addEventListener('storage', debouncedCb);`

Comment: I updated code  , that poblem are there

Comment: Well you're doing `window.addEventListener('storage', storageEventCb);` instead of `window.addEventListener('storage', debouncedCb);`!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well just set the debounced function as event listener?

```
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};

const storageEventCb = () => console.error(1); 

// Define the debounced function
const debouncedCb = debounce(storageEventCb, 1500);

window.addEventListener('storage', debouncedCb);
```