# JavaScript Events how prevent the same event to happen twice in the same time

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have an event when **user clicks on keyDown on keyboard** and it works but I want when the click happens for the second time to do something different. It works also, but *if user click on keyboard twice quickly it will make my animation not look good*. I want the second event not occur until first is finished. What should I do?

I need something make the same event uncallable until the first is done.

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {

    (e.key === "ArrowDown") ? slideDown() : null;
    (e.key === "ArrowUp") ? slideUp() : null;
    (counter === 3) ? myName.style.color = "white" : myName.style.color = "black";

})
```

Comment: Maybe using a variable to store the status?

Comment: explain more please

Comment: You need [debouncer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4298672/1169519).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the "debounce" function in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004791/what-is-the-debounce-function-in-javascript)

Comment: What does your `slideDown` function return? What does it provide to know whether it was finished?

Comment: its will add class to some element in my html to make animation start, its work but i want event doesn't happen until animation happen

Comment: Please edit your question and add the HTML and CSS class information. There are several ways animations can be triggered, and the solution is different for each of them.

Comment: i fix my problem thank god :) i use timeIntervel and setTimeout(); and it work with me to do what i want

Comment: No, using a timer for this is a horrible solution!  Each event already has a timestamp you could use. Yet, the underlying problem is with how you are doing the animation and not with the multiple keydown events.  Please edit your question per @trincot comment.