# How to wait for the 'end' of 'resize' event and only then perform an action?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, resize, jquery-events

So I currently use something like:

```
$(window).resize(function(){resizedw();});
```

But this gets called many times while resizing process goes on. Is it possible to catch an event when it ends?

Comment: Maybe attach using [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) so it only executes after all resizing is done and not over and over?

Comment: When a user resizes a window manually (by dragging it) the resize event will be called more than once, so using .one() really won't be effective.

Comment: The use of an anonymous function in the above could be removed, for simplicity and marginal rapidity: $(window).resize(resizedw)

Comment: Here is a jQuery library for this: https://github.com/nielse63/jquery.resizeend

Answer (score 201, accepted):

I had luck with the following recommendation: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/the-resizeend-event

Here's the code so you don't have to dig through his post's link & source:

```
var rtime;
var timeout = false;
var delta = 200;
$(window).resize(function() {
    rtime = new Date();
    if (timeout === false) {
        timeout = true;
        setTimeout(resizeend, delta);
    }
});

function resizeend() {
    if (new Date() - rtime < delta) {
        setTimeout(resizeend, delta);
    } else {
        timeout = false;
        alert('Done resizing');
    }               
}
```

Thanks sime.vidas for the code!

Comment: One might want to change the Date to something like `new Date(-1E12)` - ie JSLint warns about using `00`.

Comment: Thankks elundmark. I've switched date instantiation to use single 0's; hopefully that won't generate a complaint.

Comment: @elundmark or use + operation. `rtime: Date; ....        if (+new Date() - +rtime < delta)` and in typescript resizeend function should be arrow function like this `resizeend=()=>`. Because in resizeend function, `this` reference to window object.

Answer (score 614):

You can use `setTimeout()` and `clearTimeout()`

```
function resizedw(){
    // Haven't resized in 100ms!
}

var doit;
window.onresize = function(){
  clearTimeout(doit);
  doit = setTimeout(resizedw, 100);
};
```

**Code example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/fq882/197/).**

Comment: This is a great answer. It does what the plugin I recommended does, only without a plugin.

Comment: I think the only way to really improve this is to detect mouse movement. I suspect digging into it would not payoff, though.

Comment: Does this only work if the resize is finished within a second?  My function was triggering when I tried using this (I was slow w/ my window resize though)

Comment: @MichaelHaren As the re-size handle is generally outside of the `$(document)`, mouse-detection would be limited to users running Microsoft Windows and vulnerable versions of its Internet Explorer: http://iedataleak.spider.io/demo

Comment: This is a very simple implementation of the **debounce** concept (http://unscriptable.com/2009/03/20/debouncing-javascript-methods/). Paul Irish (and others) has presented a much more efficient solution which is not handling 'unnecessary' resize events: http://www.paulirish.com/2009/throttled-smartresize-jquery-event-handler/

Comment: why wouldn't JavaScript have a resizeend event?

Comment: isnt this essentially the same problem? ur only calling something else repeatedly instead of what you actually wanna do...

Comment: Utilize the debounce concept mentioned by @rmoestl.  Works perfectly. Thanks for the link to Paul Irish smartresize implementation.

Answer (score 94):

This is the code that I write according to @Mark Coleman answer:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    clearTimeout(window.resizedFinished);
    window.resizedFinished = setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('Resized finished.');
    }, 250);
});
```

Thanks Mark!

Comment: Nice approarch. Also mentioned [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/done-resizing-event/) with the difference that no modifications to the super variable _window_ is made.

Comment: @AlwinKesler - in your example the variable `resizeTimer` is a global variable, meaning it's defined no the `window`, so it's exactly the same as here, only this example is better since you don't need to define the variable externally. and it also makes sense to add this variable to the `window` object since that is the Object the event listener is binded to.

Comment: Thanks! Just wanted to add that in some cases, a longer time interval is needed to perform certain tasks in a callback.  E.g. in my case, 250 didn't work, but 700 worked great.

Comment: Nicest solution.

Answer (score 43):

Internet Explorer provides a [resizeEnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536960%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) event. Other browsers will trigger the resize event many times while you're resizing.

There are other great answers here that show how to use setTimeout and the [*.throttle*](http://lodash.com/docs#throttle), [.debounce](http://lodash.com/docs#debounce) methods from lodash and underscore, so I will mention Ben Alman's **[throttle-debounce jQuery plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/)** which accomplishes what you're after.

Suppose you have this function that you want to trigger after a resize:

```
function onResize() {
  console.log("Resize just happened!");
};
```

**Throttle Example**
In the following example, `onResize()` will only be called once every 250 milliseconds during a window resize.

```
$(window).resize( $.throttle( 250, onResize) );
```

**Debounce Example**
In the following example, `onResize()` will only be called once at the end of a window resizing action. This achieves the same result that @Mark presents in his answer.

```
$(window).resize( $.debounce( 250, onResize) );
```

Comment: Lodash is also useful here, which has _.throttle and _.debounce methods as well. I think debounce is a superior approach compared to the above accepted example.

Comment: Yeah, this answer was written over 5 years ago. A lot has happened since the jQuery plugin days. Here's a standalone debounce function too https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

Comment: A noteworthy mention should go to audit as well. It does what debounce does with an additional twist: It will make sure to also fire in between every X ms which is great during "lengthy" resizes as it guarantees that the webpage will be responsive even during the resize (neato!)

Answer (score 28):

There is an elegant solution using the [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) So, if you are using it in your project you can do the following -

```
$( window ).resize( _.debounce( resizedw, 500 ) );
```

---

This should be enough :) But, If you are interested to read more on that, you can check my blog post - <s>http://rifatnabi.com/post/detect-end-of-jquery-resize-event-using-underscore-debounce</s>(deadlink)

Comment: Just wanting to add that `lodash` also provide this

Answer (score 22):

There is a much simpler method to execute a function at the end of the resize than calculate the delta time between two calls, simply do it like this :

```
var resizeId;
$(window).resize(function() {
    clearTimeout(resizeId);
    resizeId = setTimeout(resizedEnded, 500);
});

function resizedEnded(){
    ...
}
```

And the equivalent for **Angular2** :

```
private resizeId;
@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
onResized(event: Event) {
  clearTimeout(this.resizeId);
  this.resizeId = setTimeout(() => {
    // Your callback method here.
  }, 500);
}
```

For the angular method, use the `() => { }` notation in the `setTimeout` to preserve the scope, otherwise you will not be able to make any function calls or use `this`.

Answer (score 16):

One solution is extend jQuery with a function, e.g.: `resized`

```
$.fn.resized = function (callback, timeout) {
    $(this).resize(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.data('resizeTimeout')) {
            clearTimeout($this.data('resizeTimeout'));
        }
        $this.data('resizeTimeout', setTimeout(callback, timeout));
    });
};
```

Sample usage:

`$(window).resized(myHandler, 300);`

Comment: Great solution. Thank you. How to use it for each `$(window).resized();` ? Because when I try to use more than one `$(window).resized();` only the last is executed

Comment: The way this function works is by saving data into a specific scope, so you could call it into different scopes, other than the `window` . $(scope).resized(yourHandler, 300). Or by implementing a way to save all callbacks into an array and invoke it  sequentially when the timeout has been triggered.

Answer (score 7):

You can store a reference id to any setInterval or setTimeout. Like this:

```
var loop = setInterval(func, 30);

// some time later clear the interval
clearInterval(loop);
```

To do this without a "global" variable you can add a local variable to the function itself. Ex:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    clearTimeout(this.id);
    this.id = setTimeout(doneResizing, 500);
});

function doneResizing(){
  $("body").append("<br/>done!");   
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `setTimeout()` and `clearTimeout()` in conjunction with [`jQuery.data`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/):

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    clearTimeout($.data(this, 'resizeTimer'));
    $.data(this, 'resizeTimer', setTimeout(function() {
        //do something
        alert("Haven't resized in 200ms!");
    }, 200));
});
```

**Update**

I wrote an *extension* to enhance jQuery's default `on` (& `bind`)-event-handler. It attaches an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements if the event was not triggered for a given interval. This is useful if you want to fire a callback only after a delay, like the resize event, or else.
https://github.com/yckart/jquery.unevent.js

```
;(function ($) {
    var methods = { on: $.fn.on, bind: $.fn.bind };
    $.each(methods, function(k){
        $.fn[k] = function () {
            var args = [].slice.call(arguments),
                delay = args.pop(),
                fn = args.pop(),
                timer;

            args.push(function () {
                var self = this,
                    arg = arguments;
                clearTimeout(timer);
                timer = setTimeout(function(){
                    fn.apply(self, [].slice.call(arg));
                }, delay);
            });

            return methods[k].apply(this, isNaN(delay) ? arguments : args);
        };
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Use it like any other `on` or `bind`-event handler, except that you can pass an extra parameter as a last:

```
$(window).on('resize', function(e) {
    console.log(e.type + '-event was 200ms not triggered');
}, 200);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ARTsinn/EqqHx/

Answer (score 3):

## *ResizeStart* and *ResizeEnd* events for window

http://jsfiddle.net/04fLy8t4/

I implemented a function which trigs two events on the user DOM element:

1. **resizestart**
2. **resizeend**

Code:

```
var resizeEventsTrigger = (function () {
    function triggerResizeStart($el) {
        $el.trigger('resizestart');
        isStart = !isStart;
    }

    function triggerResizeEnd($el) {
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        timeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
            $el.trigger('resizeend');
            isStart = !isStart;
        }, delay);
    }

    var isStart = true;
    var delay = 200;
    var timeoutId;

    return function ($el) {
        isStart ? triggerResizeStart($el) : triggerResizeEnd($el);
    };

})();

$("#my").on('resizestart', function () {
    console.log('resize start');
});
$("#my").on('resizeend', function () {
    console.log('resize end');
});

window.onresize = function () {
    resizeEventsTrigger( $("#my") );
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Mark Coleman's answer is certainly far better than the selected answer, but if you want to avoid the global variable for the timeout ID (the `doit` variable in Mark's answer), you could do one of the following:

(1) Use a an immediately invoked function expression (IIFE) to create a closure.

```
$(window).resize((function() { // This function is immediately invoked
                               // and returns the closure function.
    var timeoutId;
    return function() {
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
            timeoutId = null; // You could leave this line out.
            // Code to execute on resize goes here.
        }, 100);
    };
})());
```

(2) Use a property of the event handler function.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var thisFunction = arguments.callee;
    clearTimeout(thisFunction.timeoutId);
    thisFunction.timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
        thisFunction.timeoutId = null; // You could leave this line out.
        // Code to execute on resize goes here.
    }, 100);
});
```

Comment: Option 2, using arguments.callee, will not work if the function is transpiled from ES6.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I use for delaying repeated actions, it can be called in multiple places in your code:

```
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};
```

Usage:

```
$(window).resize(function () { 
   debounce(function() {
          //...
    }, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a modification to Dolan's code above, I've added a feature which checks the window size at the start of the resize and compares it to the size at the end of the resize, if size is either bigger or smaller than the margin (eg. 1000) then it reloads.

```
var rtime = new Date(1, 1, 2000, 12,00,00);
var timeout = false;
var delta = 200;
var windowsize = $window.width();
var windowsizeInitial = $window.width();

$(window).on('resize',function() {
    windowsize = $window.width();
    rtime = new Date();
    if (timeout === false) {
            timeout = true;
            setTimeout(resizeend, delta);
        }
});

function resizeend() {
if (new Date() - rtime < delta) {
    setTimeout(resizeend, delta);
    return false;
} else {
        if (windowsizeInitial > 1000 && windowsize > 1000 ) {
            setTimeout(resizeend, delta);
            return false;
        }
        if (windowsizeInitial < 1001 && windowsize < 1001 ) {
            setTimeout(resizeend, delta);
            return false;
        } else {
            timeout = false;
            location.reload();
        }
    }
    windowsizeInitial = $window.width();
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is VERY simple script to trigger both a 'resizestart' and 'resizeend' event on the window object.

There is no need to muck around with dates and times.

The `d` variable represents the number of milliseconds between resize events before triggering the resize end event, you can play with this to change how sensitive the end event is.

To listen to these events all you need to do is:

resizestart: `$(window).on('resizestart', function(event){console.log('Resize Start!');});`

resizeend:
`$(window).on('resizeend', function(event){console.log('Resize End!');});`

```
(function ($) {
    var d = 250, t = null, e = null, h, r = false;

    h = function () {
        r = false;
        $(window).trigger('resizeend', e);
    };

    $(window).on('resize', function (event) {
        e = event || e;
        clearTimeout(t);

        if (!r) {
            $(window).trigger('resizestart', e);
            r = true;
        }

        t = setTimeout(h, d);
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: I needed the start and ends of the resize, and this looks like it works well (tested in Chrome, FF, Opera, and IE11). For testing I created a JSFiddle with your solution: https://jsfiddle.net/8fsn2joj/

Answer (score 2):

I took a slightly different tack and relied on `mouseUp` as the end of the `resize` event. `trackSize` is called on `documentReady` and the initial value of `wide` is set then, too.

```
  var THRESHOLD = 784;
  var TALL = 125, SHORT = 50;
  var wide = (window.document.body.clientWidth >= THRESHOLD );

  function trackSize() {
    if( !wide ) {
      setHeight( TALL );
    } else {
      setHeight( SHORT );
    }
    parent.window.addEventListener('resize', onResize);
  }
  function onResize(e) {
    parent.window.removeEventListener('resize', onResize);
    parent.window.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp) ;
  }
  function onMouseUp(e) {
    parent.window.removeEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);
    wide = (window.document.body.clientWidth >= THRESHOLD);
    trackSize();
  }
```

After having set our window's initial height, we begin listening for a `resize` event. When it starts, we stop listening and start listening for the `mouseUp` event.  Thus, we know that `mouseUp` will end the resizing.  In `mouseUp`, we stop listening and set a toggle based on the window's width, then loop back to `trackSize`.

`trackSize` starts by setting the window's height based on the toggle -- if below the threshold, we increase height (because Bootstrap columns stack at small widths), otherwise set to standard.  And then we listen again for the next `resize` event.

**CAVEAT:** This solution doesn't really work for resizing instantly using the maximize or restore window buttons. Maybe adding a test like `isMouseDown` and bypassing the mouse listener would suffice - I haven't yet tested that.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as far as the window manager is concerned, each resize event is its own message, with a distinct beginning and end, so technically, every time the window is resized, it **is** the end.

Having said that, maybe you want to set a delay to your continuation? [Here's an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/gKCQE/1/)

```
var t = -1;
function doResize()
{
    document.write('resize');
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
        clearTimeout(t);
        t = setTimeout(doResize, 1000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

i wrote a litte wrapper function on my own...

```
onResize  =   function(fn) {
    if(!fn || typeof fn != 'function')
        return 0;

    var args    = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);

    onResize.fnArr    = onResize.fnArr || [];
    onResize.fnArr.push([fn, args]);

    onResize.loop   = function() {
        $.each(onResize.fnArr, function(index, fnWithArgs) {
            fnWithArgs[0].apply(undefined, fnWithArgs[1]);
        });
    };

    $(window).on('resize', function(e) {
        window.clearTimeout(onResize.timeout);
        onResize.timeout    = window.setTimeout("onResize.loop();", 300);
    });
};
```

Here is the usage:

```
var testFn  = function(arg1, arg2) {
    console.log('[testFn] arg1: '+arg1);
    console.log('[testFn] arg2: '+arg2);
};

// document ready
$(function() {
    onResize(testFn, 'argument1', 'argument2');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(function(){
    var special = jQuery.event.special,
        uid1 = 'D' + (+new Date()),
        uid2 = 'D' + (+new Date() + 1);

    special.resizestart = {
        setup: function() {
            var timer,
                handler =  function(evt) {
                    var _self = this,
                        _args = arguments;
                    if (timer) {
                        clearTimeout(timer);
                    } else {
                        evt.type = 'resizestart';
                        jQuery.event.handle.apply(_self, _args);
                    }

                    timer = setTimeout( function(){
                        timer = null;
                    }, special.resizestop.latency);
                };
            jQuery(this).bind('resize', handler).data(uid1, handler);
        },
        teardown: function(){
            jQuery(this).unbind( 'resize', jQuery(this).data(uid1) );
        }
    };

    special.resizestop = {
        latency: 200,
        setup: function() {
            var timer,
                handler = function(evt) {
                    var _self = this,
                        _args = arguments;
                    if (timer) {
                        clearTimeout(timer);
                    }
                    timer = setTimeout( function(){
                        timer = null;
                        evt.type = 'resizestop';
                        jQuery.event.handle.apply(_self, _args);
                    }, special.resizestop.latency);
                };

            jQuery(this).bind('resize', handler).data(uid2, handler);
        },
        teardown: function() {
            jQuery(this).unbind( 'resize', jQuery(this).data(uid2) );
        }
    };
})();

$(window).bind('resizestop',function(){
    //...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess my case might be different from some others but I had a problem only with orientation change on iOS but wanted the resize event to run immediately. I used the `ScreenOrientation` API:

```
screen.orientation.addEventListener('change', (e) => {});
```

Answer (score 0):

since the selected answer didn't actually work .. and if you're not using jquery here is a simple throttle function with an example of how to use it with window resizing

```
    function throttle(end,delta) {

    var base = this;

    base.wait = false;
    base.delta = 200;
    base.end = end;

    base.trigger = function(context) {

        //only allow if we aren't waiting for another event
        if ( !base.wait ) {

            //signal we already have a resize event
            base.wait = true;

            //if we are trying to resize and we 
            setTimeout(function() {

                //call the end function
                if(base.end) base.end.call(context);

                //reset the resize trigger
                base.wait = false;
            }, base.delta);
        }
    }
};

var windowResize = new throttle(function() {console.log('throttle resize');},200);

window.onresize = function(event) {
    windowResize.trigger();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### UPDATE!

**Better alternative also created by me is here:**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23692008/2829600
(supports "delete functions")

### ORIGINAL POST:

I wrote this simple function for handling delay in execution, useful inside jQuery .scroll() and .resize() So callback_f will run only once for specific id string.

```
function delay_exec( id, wait_time, callback_f ){

    // IF WAIT TIME IS NOT ENTERED IN FUNCTION CALL,
    // SET IT TO DEFAULT VALUE: 0.5 SECOND
    if( typeof wait_time === "undefined" )
        wait_time = 500;

    // CREATE GLOBAL ARRAY(IF ITS NOT ALREADY CREATED)
    // WHERE WE STORE CURRENTLY RUNNING setTimeout() FUNCTION FOR THIS ID
    if( typeof window['delay_exec'] === "undefined" )
        window['delay_exec'] = [];

    // RESET CURRENTLY RUNNING setTimeout() FUNCTION FOR THIS ID,
    // SO IN THAT WAY WE ARE SURE THAT callback_f WILL RUN ONLY ONE TIME
    // ( ON LATEST CALL ON delay_exec FUNCTION WITH SAME ID  )
    if( typeof window['delay_exec'][id] !== "undefined" )
        clearTimeout( window['delay_exec'][id] );

    // SET NEW TIMEOUT AND EXECUTE callback_f WHEN wait_time EXPIRES,
    // BUT ONLY IF THERE ISNT ANY MORE FUTURE CALLS ( IN wait_time PERIOD )
    // TO delay_exec FUNCTION WITH SAME ID AS CURRENT ONE
    window['delay_exec'][id] = setTimeout( callback_f , wait_time );
}


// USAGE

jQuery(window).resize(function() {

    delay_exec('test1', 1000, function(){
        console.log('1st call to delay "test1" successfully executed!');
    });

    delay_exec('test1', 1000, function(){
        console.log('2nd call to delay "test1" successfully executed!');
    });

    delay_exec('test1', 1000, function(){
        console.log('3rd call to delay "test1" successfully executed!');
    });

    delay_exec('test2', 1000, function(){
        console.log('1st call to delay "test2" successfully executed!');
    });

    delay_exec('test3', 1000, function(){
        console.log('1st call to delay "test3" successfully executed!');
    });

});

/* RESULT
3rd call to delay "test1" successfully executed!
1st call to delay "test2" successfully executed!
1st call to delay "test3" successfully executed!
*/
```

Comment: Could you clarify usage here? Are you suggesting one does: `$(window).resize(function() { delay_exec('test1', 30, function() { ... delayed stuff here ... }); });`? Pretty clean code otherwise. Thanks for sharing. :)

Comment: You rock! Thanks @Déján! +1 all the way. Cool code example, it works very well from what I have tested. Simple to use, too. Thanks again for sharing. :)

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me as I did not want to use any plugins.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var originalWindowSize = 0;
    var currentWidth = 0;

    var setFn = function () {
        originalWindowSize = $(window).width();
    };

    var checkFn = function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            currentWidth = $(window).width();
            if (currentWidth === originalWindowSize) {
                console.info("same? = yes") 
                // execute code 
            } else {
                console.info("same? = no"); 
                // do nothing 
            }
        }, 500)
    };
    setFn();
    checkFn();
});
```

On window re-size invoke "setFn" which gets width of window and save as "originalWindowSize". Then invoke "checkFn" which after 500ms (or your preference) gets the current window size, and compares the original to the current, if they are not the same, then the window is still being re-sized. Don't forget to remove console messages in production, and (optional) can make "setFn" self executing.

Answer (score 0):

```
var resizeTimer;
$( window ).resize(function() {
    if(resizeTimer){
        clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
    }
    resizeTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        //your code here
        resizeTimer = null;
        }, 200);
    });
```

This worked for what I was trying to do in chrome. This won't fire the callback until 200ms after last resize event.

Answer (score 0):

```
var flag=true;
var timeloop;

$(window).resize(function(){
    rtime=new Date();
    if(flag){
        flag=false;
        timeloop=setInterval(function(){
            if(new Date()-rtime>100)
                myAction();
        },100);
    }
})
function myAction(){
    clearInterval(timeloop);
    flag=true;
    //any other code...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know is my code work for other but it's really do a great job for me. I got this idea by analyzing Dolan Antenucci code because his version is not work for me and I really hope it'll be helpful to someone.

```
var tranStatus = false;
$(window).resizeend(200, function(){
    $(".cat-name, .category").removeAttr("style");
    //clearTimeout(homeResize);
    $("*").one("webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend",function(event) {
      tranStatus = true;
    });
    processResize();
});

function processResize(){
  homeResize = setInterval(function(){
    if(tranStatus===false){
        console.log("not yet");
        $("*").one("webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend",function(event) {
            tranStatus = true;
        }); 
    }else{
        text_height();
        clearInterval(homeResize);
    }
  },200);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function that passes a function when wrapped in any resize event. It uses an interval so that the resize even isn't constantly creating timeout events. This allows it to perform independently of the resize event other than a log entry that should be removed in production.

https://github.com/UniWrighte/resizeOnEnd/blob/master/resizeOnEnd.js

```
        $(window).resize(function(){
            //call to resizeEnd function to execute function on resize end.
    //can be passed as function name or anonymous function
            resizeEnd(function(){



    });

        });

        //global variables for reference outside of interval
        var interval = null;
        var width = $(window).width();
    var numi = 0; //can be removed in production
        function resizeEnd(functionCall){
            //check for null interval
            if(!interval){
                //set to new interval
                interval = setInterval(function(){
        //get width to compare
                    width2 = $(window).width();
        //if stored width equals new width
                    if(width === width2){
                        //clear interval, set to null, and call passed function
                        clearInterval(interval);
                        interval = null; //precaution
                        functionCall();

                    }
        //set width to compare on next interval after half a second
                    width = $(window).width();
                }, 500);

            }else{
                //logging that should be removed in production
                console.log("function call " + numi++ + " and inteval set skipped");

            }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver((entries) => {
    for (const entry of entries) {
        entry.target.addEventListener("mouseup", resizeEnded)
    }
});

function resizeEnded(ev) {
    ev.target.removeEventListener('mouseup', resizeEnded)

    /* do something after resize ended */
}

let elm = document.createElement("div");
resizeObserver.observe(elm);
```