# flexslider slideshow not resizing properly

Tags: resize, carousel, flexslider

I have set up the Flexslider Carousel with thumbs on my website.  For some reason, when I shrink it below a certain size it does not re-size properly and then it disappears (overflow: hidden could be causing this second issue)  I freely admit that my java skills are limited, so I hope that someone here will be able to tell me what I messed up...

http://studiobilodeau.com/VLSB/slideshows/the_body2.php

Thanks for any help!
v

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FlexSlider 2 resizing on window resize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11818356/flexslider-2-resizing-on-window-resize)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, give your containing div (#container) width either in %, so that it adjusts as per your browser window or set its width for different viewports.