# How to reinitialize flexslider for a dynamic loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, flexslider

I got a problem with flexslider, I need to download my picture in base64 from a webservice.
After the download is complete, I make an `.append()` to add my slide...

But sometimes, everything is added perfectly but the slider doesn't reload correctly 
So I get code like this :
[image: screen1]

instead of code like this :
[image: screen2]

How can I reinitiate my slider in this case ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Solution found !
Just add this line of code to remove the old slider ref if exists

`$('#flexslider').removeData("flexslider");`

Comment: Your answer was very useful for me !

Comment: @AlxAlx I am getting the same problem, in my case slider is initializing in normal way but images are not loading.(here whole slider inner content is coming dynamically). Any idea how to get those images?

Comment: flexslider + knockout.js + this answer = amazing

Comment: Dude, your answer saved my as*. I am very grateful for your answer. Thank You.

Comment: You da best. This was exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 8):

When the download is complete, and after you make the append, try using the method again.

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider();
```

That should reinitiate it and account for new content.