# jQuery orientation with $(window).resize ooops

Tags: jquery, orientation, window-resize, landscape-portrait

i am trying to achieve the folowing:
The website i am working on works better on landscape mode.
i want that when the device is on Portrait a message is displayed and when on Landscape the message is not displayed.

i have written, inside the ready() function, the following code:

```
    $(window).resize( function(){

    var height = $(window).height();
    var width = $(window).width(); 

    if(width>height) {
        // Landscape
        $("#landscape").css('display','none');
    }   
    else {
        // Portrait
        $("#landscape").css('display','block');
        $("#landscape").click(function(){
            $(this).hide();
        });
    }
```

but when the page loads (or i refresh it) it ALWAYS shows the the message (as it should only in portrait mode). If i then change the browser size the code starts working and shows/hides the message accordingly.
How could i fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `.resize()` after `$(window).resize()`:

```
$(window).resize( function(){

  var height = $(window).height();
  var width = $(window).width(); 

  if(width>height) {
    // Landscape
    $("#landscape").css('display','none');
  } else {
    // Portrait
    $("#landscape").css('display','block');
    $("#landscape").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
  }
}).resize(); // <----this way
```

Answer (score 0):

Trigger your function when the DOM is ready.

```
$(function() {
    $(window).resize();
});
```

Comment: i tried, but i still get the message even when the browser is in "landscape mode" on refresh...

Comment: ...and i also noticed that on refresh the function is not working. when i click the message it does not hide (but it does hide then when the message is shown on resizing the browser)...

Answer (score 0):

The ready() function will just fire once on load.  You need to take this outside of the ready function and just call it ONCE on load and then work if the window has been re-sized.

Also, when using $(window).resize, make sure you set a time delay to prevent multiple concurrent occurrences, this has been covered many times:

[JavaScript/JQuery: $(window).resize how to fire AFTER the resize is completed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854407/javascript-jquery-window-resize-how-to-fire-after-the-resize-is-completed)

[jQuery - how to wait for the 'end' of 'resize' event and only then perform an action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489946/jquery-how-to-wait-for-the-end-or-resize-event-and-only-then-perform-an-ac)

Not sure what your project scope is, but handling a project solely based on orientation is normally considered a bad practice; especially in your landscape function ( width>height ).  What if a page width spans 1280 across and  500 in height?  Unless you are also using device detection, your logic will not always hold true.

Comment: thanks. i have made the media queries so the site works both on Portrait and on Landscape modes. But i still would like a message to inform the user that the design is nicer on Landscape. then it is up to the user to decide either to continue on Portrait (click) on change to Landscape (rotate). But thank you, that was a nice tip...