# Stop script from working if screen size is smaller than

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry

I have this small snippet of jQuery:

```
if (jQuery(window).innerWidth() > 568) {
    jQuery('#boardOfTrustees').masonry({
        itemSelector: '.postWrapper',
    });
}
```

This works fine, but I want to stop this from working, or uninitialize it on resize if the screen is smaller than a certain size.  I've tried this:

```
jQuery(window).smartresize(function() {
    if (jQuery(window).innerWidth() > 568) {
        jQuery('#boardOfTrustees').masonry({
            itemSelector: '.postWrapper',
        });
    }   
});
```

`.smartresize` is a debounce script, it works well, but for this particular scenario, its not doing anything and the masonry script is still initialized.  How can I make first set of jQuery stop applying itself to the elements if the screen is smaller than 568 pixels but then start working again if the resize is larger than 568?

Comment: you can't stop something that has already happened. you can only undo it.

Comment: Is it possible that the window is wide enough at the start so `masonry` is called? I think you need to explicitly undo whatever `masonry` does if the width is `<= 568`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work on load. Not on resize:

```
if (jQuery(window).innerWidth() < 568) {
    jQuery('#boardOfTrustees').masonry({
        itemSelector: '.postWrapper',
    });
}
```

To make it work on resize then you would need to use the method `destroy` as detailed [at the documentation.](http://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html)

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    if (jQuery(window).innerWidth() < 568) {
        jQuery('#boardOfTrustees').masonry('destroy');
    } else {
        jQuery('#boardOfTrustees').masonry({
            itemSelector: '.postWrapper',
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I know, that's exactly what I want to happen, but then also watch for resize and stop working if its smaller than 568.

Comment: I made a typo, and you copied it, the width check should actually be `< 569`.  My mistake, sorry.  So the destroy method seems to partially work, however it leaves behind some random styles on the elements.  Any suggestions on that?  Not sure how I missed the destroy method, I checked the docs several times.

Comment: @AndyWarren about the styles you will have to ask to the creator of the plugin or its issues forum.

Comment: If this solved your problem it would be nice if you accept it as the valid answer. It might help future people.

Comment: I will definitely, sorry, was just messing with it.  It hasn't solved it yet, but its very close.  Its the right solution, I just have to get it to work correctly.  Thanks.

Comment: @Alvaro I want to ask something. Is there  any case to get performance drawbacks from re-initialize the plug in over and over, all the time? I take as example a user with a laptop. The user maybe will resize the window regularly. Isn't there any cost by using it?

Comment: @GeorgeGkas of course it is. But you can always use a timeout to only fire the resize event every X milliseconds after the user stopped resizing. So it won't fire while resizing. Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5490021/1081396)

Answer (score 0):

Destroy it

```
else {
    jQuery('#boardOfTrustees').masonry('destroy')
}
```