# repeat an else/if closure function on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, resize

so i have this function:

```
(function() {

    var wwidth = $(window).width();

    function headroom() {

        // headroom

        $("nav").headroom({
            "tolerance" : 0,
            "offset" : 1300,

        });

        // to destroy
        $("nav").headroom("destroy");

    }

    function headroomMobile() {

        // headroom

        $("#nav-wrap").headroom({
            "tolerance" : 0,
            "offset" : 200,

        });

        // to destroy
        $("#nav-wrap").headroom("destroy");

    }

    if (wwidth >= 480) {

        headroom();
    }
    if (wwidth < 480) {

        headroomMobile();
    }



})();
```

i would this function to repeat everytime there's a window resize but i can't make it to work, maybe because it's a closure function.. i tried naming the whole function and trigger it on window.resize but it didn't work, i probably did some syntax error or misplaced the bit of code. I'm sure it's no difficult task but i can't make it to work :\ can you help?

thank you so much!

Comment: Remove the IIFE, make it a named function instead, and execute it on pageload and on window resize.

Comment: could you help me with the code? thanks!

Comment: your looking for the `resize` event of the `window` object `window.addEventListener("resize",headroom,false);` or since your using jquery `$(window).resize(headroom);`

Answer (score 0):

If you want a function to be called everything the window is resized then just bind it to the

resize event like so:

```
(function () {

    var wwidth = $(window).width();

    function headroom() {

        // headroom

        $("nav").headroom({
            "tolerance": 0,
            "offset": 1300,

        });

        // to destroy
        $("nav").headroom("destroy");

    }

    function headroomMobile() {

        // headroom

        $("#nav-wrap").headroom({
            "tolerance": 0,
            "offset": 200,

        });

        // to destroy
        $("#nav-wrap").headroom("destroy");

    }

    function setHeader() {
        if (wwidth >= 480) {
            headroom();
        } else {
            headroomMobile();
        }
    }

    setHeader(); // on load

    $(window).resize(function () {
        wwidth = $(window).width();
        setHeader();
    });

})();
```

But this is not the most efficient way to do it.. checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489946/jquery-how-to-wait-for-the-end-or-resize-event-and-only-then-perform-an-ac)

Comment: actually i want to fire onload and to repeat also on window.resize. is that possible?

Comment: thanks lucky i saw your edits, i pasted this code but nothing happens at this point

Comment: sorry i missed the last `()` .. please try now.

Answer (score 0):

Make it a named function, and use it for both things:

```
(function() {
    function handleWindowSizing() {
        // ...logic here...
    }

    $(window).load(handleWindowSizing).resize(handleWindowSizing);
})();
```

Note that the `load` event on `window` handles *really late* in the page load process, you may want to do your logic right away as well (make sure your code is at the very end of the HTML so that anything it acts on has been parsed and put in the DOM). E.g.:

```
<!-- ...content... -->
<script>
(function() {
    function handleWindowSizing() {
        // ...logic here...
    }

    handleWindowSizing();    
    $(window).load(handleWindowSizing).resize(handleWindowSizing);
})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @omegaiori: Sounds like some unrelated error occurs, check your console.

Comment: @omegaiori: That's unfortunate. You'll have to walk through with the debugger, because there **is** something unrelated to the question going on. The above works - http://jsbin.com/beficace/1