# jQuery dynamically set incremented height to elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

**What I want to achieve**:

for each `ul.container` -> find the greatest `li` height -> **add 25px to it** -> apply that new height to all `li` within the container.

I need the calculation to happen also on window resize.

**The problem**:

While this works at page load, when resizing the browser window, the height keeps incrementing by 25px at every loop. I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

**My code**:

```
function listHeight() {

    $("ul.container").each(function () {

        var listHeight = 0;
        var newHeight = 0;

        $("li", this).each(function () {

            newHeight = $(this).height();

            if (newHeight > listHeight) {

                listHeight = newHeight;
            }
        });

        $("li", this).height(listHeight += 25);
    });
}

listHeight();

$(window).resize(function () {
    listHeight();
});
```

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/VtypM/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have done it once on page load (i.e. set the height of all list elements to x).  What's the point of doing it all again when the window is resized? - The height of all items are already x and then you just keep adding 25!

Comment: @StephenMuecke because I need different calculations for responsive purposes. I am resetting everything to zero before calculating again.

Comment: yes @MrUpsidown you are resetting variables but "Li"'s physical height is increasing continuously. see my answer below it will solve your problem

Comment: No you're not. Look at your code again. On the first time (load) the height of all items is say 50.  The next time your getting the maximum height (the loop is pointless since they are all 50) and then adding 25 - it will just keep growing infinitely.

Comment: @JeetendraChauhan Yup yup! Got it now! Thanks.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Right. I was resetting the variables but not the elements height, which was the issue here (not the resize).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The height increases because you set the height in the first run. After that the height remains the "max hight" + 25 and adds additional 25 to it.
To prevent that just reset the height of the element to auto.

```
function listHeight() {
    $("ul.container").each(function () {
        var listHeight = 0;
        var newHeight = 0;

        $("li", this).each(function () {
            var el = $(this);
            el.css('height', 'auto');
            newHeight = el.height();

            if (newHeight > listHeight) {
                listHeight = newHeight;
            }
        });

        $("li", this).height(listHeight += 25);
    });
}

listHeight();

$(window).resize(function () {
    listHeight();
});
```

For better performance I suggest that you debounce/throttle the function call.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add

```
$("li", this).height("auto");
```

after

```
var listHeight = 0;
var newHeight = 0;
```

view [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VtypM/3/)

Comment: Good catch! I knew I was just missing something :-)

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to look at this thread.
[jQuery - how to wait for the 'end' of 'resize' event and only then perform an action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489946/jquery-how-to-wait-for-the-end-or-resize-event-and-only-then-perform-an-ac)

You need to call it at the end of the resize event.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

You need to increment height only if newHeight > listHeight, I think.