# Issue with JQuery window resize function calls

Tags: event-handling, resize, window-resize

I have a resize method in my js file :

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    my_function();
});
```

In it i have loads of other functions which need to be called when the window is resized (for the responsive part of a website) ,i have not included all these functions as the problem i keep facing is the same in the one i am about to post.

It can't be simpler :

```
function my_function() {
    console.log('1');
    $('body').click(function(){
        console.log('2');
    });
   }
   my_function();
//when the function is called the console logs 1,when you click on the body ,it logs 2.
```

Now the problem, when I resize the window (for example : from full window to half in 2s),the resize() fires a couple of times (for example :  **10** [every time it's different]).I know this because in the console the number `1` is called/logged 10 times as the window is being resized.Now,after i finished resizing the window, when i click on the body, the console logs the number `2` the same amount of times (**10**). 
Why ? And how can i make it fire the `click.function` only once ?

Alex.

UPDATE 1 : in addition,every subsequent click on the body logs `2` another **10** times (so if i click 5 times,the console will log the number `2` 50 times.

Comment: I think this what you need. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489946/jquery-how-to-wait-for-the-end-of-resize-event-and-only-then-perform-an-ac

Comment: It made a slight difference,but the issue still persists.