# Detect when window resize event is done

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize

I have a site that needs to reload after resizing and have found my own limit of coding a script, that automatically reloads the page:

**I want the script to behave like follows:**

> if window width was `< 768px` and stays `< 768px` I do **not** want to reload the page
>
> if window width was `>= 768px` and goes `< 768px` I want to reload the page once
>
> if window width was `< 768px` and goes `>= 768px` I want to reload the page
>
> if window width was `>= 768px` and stays `>= 768px` it always should reload

The last part is done easy using the following code:

```
// After resize events
var id;
$(window).resize(function() {
    clearTimeout(id);
    id = setTimeout(doneResizing, 500);
});
function doneResizing(){
    if($(window).width() > 767) {
        if (window.RT) clearTimeout(window.RT);
          window.RT = setTimeout(function()
          {
            this.location.reload(false); /* false to get page from cache */
          }, 200);
    }
}
```

I think I have to create a `var` that stores the current `$(window).width();` and than check with `if {} else if {} else {}`, but from this point my mind looses the control.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489946/jquery-how-to-wait-for-the-end-of-resize-event-and-only-then-perform-an-ac

Comment: Why is it the page needs to reload? If it's a styling issue, you may want to look into Media Queries

Comment: @JonathonBlok I have a few scripts, that I am not able to "remove", after I have added them, and although the site does calculate a lot of heights and widths, wich need to be recalculated, as soon as the window size changes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// After resize events
var id;
var startWidth = window.innerWidth; //get the original screen width

$(window).resize(function() {
    clearTimeout(id);
    id = setTimeout(doneResizing, 500);
});
function doneResizing(){
    if ($(window).width() > 767) {
        this.location.reload(false);
    } else {
        if (startWidth > 767){
            this.location.reload(false);                
        }
    }
}
```