# Making D3 responsive: viewBox vs resize()?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have to build d3 visualisations that work well both on tablets, Desktop displays, and in some cases very very large 4k+ high resolution cinema size displays.

So I'm trying to figure out what the trade off is between using SVG's 'viewBox' attribute with 'preserveaspectratio' vs having a resize function called to re-render on window resize events and use absolute values.  Most examples, such as this blog entry (http://eyeseast.github.io/visible-data/2013/08/28/responsive-charts-with-d3/) suggest the latter in which I do something like this:

```
d3.select(window).on('resize', resize)

resize() {
// rerender each individual element with the new width+height of the parent node
d3.select('svg')
 .attr('width', newWidth)
//etc... and many lines of code depending upon how complex my visualisation is
}
```

However, why can't I just use SVG viewBox to let my SVG resize like so:

```
d3.select('svg')
  .attr( 'preserveAspectRatio',"xMinYMin meet")
  .attr("viewBox", "0 0 900 500")
  .attr('width', '100%')
```

I just make everything assuming that my width and height are 900x500px (or whatever), and leverage the fact that SVG is a vector format that takes care of all the **fiddly details such as text sizes and margins**. I'm struggling to see why so many people when giving examples of responsive or scalable visualisations using D3 favour a resize() function, and I'm **very worried that I'm missing something if I go down the viewBox route.**

### Edit:

So in addition to what mef has said below, one thought is that with a viewBox I'm stuck with a particular aspect ratio. So I might want the height of the visualisation to stay fixed such as in the case of a line or bar chart, but it has it be responsive on its width. With a fixed aspect ratio this isn't possible as changes in width require changes in height. This case requires a resize() function that re-renders to fit to the new aspect ratio.

So although a viewBox with a fixed aspect ratio is significantly easier to implement, there are a lot of common cases that require greater control, which necessitates a resize() function and explains the community preference for the more complicated solution as a first and last resort. My use case probably favours the viewBox solution, which is slightly unusual when your requirement is responsiveness.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd recommend using the following logic:

- If your visualization is usable in the smallest screens you want to support with the viewBox technique, stick to that, no need to look further (lucky you :))
- Otherwise: you may have the following problems when scaling down the visualizations:

  - there are too many details, that cannot be distinguished in smaller screens
  - the texts are too small and not readable in the smaller screens

Then you need to use javascript to adapt your visualization based on the screen size. This [blog article](https://web.archive.org/web/20160312004156/https://www.safaribooksonline.com/blog/2014/02/17/building-responsible-visualizations-d3-js/) which is serious about visualizations' responsiveness.

Oh, and don't forget to [debounce your resize event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489946/jquery-how-to-wait-for-the-end-of-resize-event-and-only-then-perform-an-ac).

Comment: I guess that in my case I have the unusual problem of scaling up rather than scaling down. Going from large tablets and desktop displays to video walls with high resolutions and screen size.

Comment: The blog article link has gone away.

Comment: Thanks. I just updated the link to point to an archived copy of the article.