# Problematic browser performance when attaching event handler inside loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a problem when creating plugin. The problem came up when setting new value for variable `width`.

`width` variable need to **calculate again**, if user resizes his  **browser**.
If i attach `resize` event inside loop, it will make **trouble performance**.
I came up with the idea to create `closure` function for wrapping all CODE. So, when the user resize his browser, i call this function again.

**JS :**

```
var self         = this,
    onScrollbarY = function() {
        self.each(function() {  // loop it
            var el           = $(this),
                elLog        = el.find(".scrollbarYLog"),
                width        = $(window).innerWidth(),    // this value will change based on users browser width
                onMouseOver  = function() {
                    elLog.html(width);
                };
            elLog.on("mouseover", onMouseOver);
        });
    };
onScrollbarY(); // call it immediatly

$(window).on("resize", onScrollbarY); // if users resize its browser, call it again for getting new browser width
```

Is this the correct way to accompolished it? or there are other option which more efficient rather than attach all code again?

Comment: There is a technique called `debouncing.`  A quick SO search brought up this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489946/jquery-how-to-wait-for-the-end-of-resize-event-and-only-then-perform-an-ac, but you might want to search for others. -- Better link to a generic debouncer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298612/jquery-how-to-call-resize-event-only-once-its-finished-resizing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you had a performance problem in the first place is that every time you called `.on('resize', ...)`, you registered a function that runs on that event. So after 5 `resize` events, you had 5 functions that were called every time, which is what caused the slow-down.

There are two ways to approach this problem:

1. only attach one handler to that event (what you ended up doing); or
2. use the [`.one('resize', ...)`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) event handler to register a function that will only be triggered on the first next `resize` event.

Use case #1 is what the majority of developers use and recommend. You create a function (like your `onScrollbarY`) and you register that function using `.on()` to be called each time the `resize` event happens from the moment you register it.

The case #2 is very rare and you probably don't want to use `.one()` unless you only want to handle the first occurence of that event, and none after that. If you wanted to handle more than one, you would have to call `.one()` again after the event happens to tell it to listen for that event again.

**EDIT:** You can simplify your code to the following:

```js
var $window  = $(window),
    width    = $window.innerWidth(), // we know the initial width
    $elLog   = $(".scrollbarYLog"),  // we find the scrollbar element
    onResize = function() {
      width = $window.innerWidth();
    },
    onMouseOver = function() {
      $elLog.html(width);
    };

// register the resize function with the "resize" event
$window.on("resize", onResize);
// register the mouseover function with the "mouseover" event on the scrollbar
$elLog.on("mouseover", onMouseOver);

// there is no need to call onResize(), as we've already set the width variable
```

Comment: thanks Klemen for answering! your explanation is very cool. i'm just wondering, if i call `onScrollbarY` 5 times or more. will `elLog.on("mouseover", onMouseOver);` also attach 5 times, or it will replace from current event? i'm just worry about the perfomance when its resize too much.

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `.on()` inside a loop, since each time `onScrolbarY` is called, it would add another function to execute during `mouseover`. You should register `on('mouseover')` outside of `onScrollbarY`.

Comment: something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/njm50ero/ please correct it if i'm wrong