# How to wait for the browser to finishing reflow in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

In javascript I have this window resize event defined

```
    $(window).resize(function() {

    })
```

but inside, I need to get width of elements. The problem is, the dimensions I am getting are for the state of how it looked before the reflow, when I need to get the dimensions after the reflow.

I tried putting a timeout of 1ms, but it doesn't seem to work. If I do 100ms, then it does. But I don't link this method, is there a better way?

**EDIT**: The function gets called **once** but its just that it needs to wait until after the redraw.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery - how to wait for the 'end' of 'resize' event and only then perform an action?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489946/jquery-how-to-wait-for-the-end-of-resize-event-and-only-then-perform-an-ac)

Comment: It's not that I'm getting multiple event fires on the resize (i.e. it only gets called once), but I just need to wait until after the browser redraw.

Comment: The resize event is fired after the document has been resized, but apparently fires before all redrawing has been completed. Maybe it´s possible to make use of RequestAnimationFrame to determine if the browser is (almost) done. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/resize and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Answer (score 0):

You should use `document.ready` like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).resize(function() {
    ///Your code
  });
});
```

Comment: I did, but that's not what I mean. The redraw happens on every resize. So **inside** the resize, I need to somehow wait for the redraw to finish.