# Display: block; based on number of list items in ul

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a responsive panel that changes based on the width of the web browser. Based on the number of list items I want a block to be displayed. For instance, if there are two list items I want the block to be displayed at window width of 500px.

**My question is:** What would be the best and most optimized method for doing this?

Current code to get number of list items in ul:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("#ulClass li").length
```

My current thought is to use a switch on a window resize event:

```js
window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
  // do stuff here
});
```

Note:

1. I need to use plain JavaScript, no plug-ins, etc.
2. I can't use Resize Observer.

Comment: We can use css media queries instead of javascript. Is there any limitation of media query you are facing ?

Comment: Use the resize function a you mentioned, but implement a timeout. That what you dont need massive computing.

Comment: @Niklas That sounds like a great idea. Can you point me in the direction of what I should look for in order to implement a timeout?

Comment: @Priyanka Thanks for the suggestion, however I can't change the layout using media queries as they can't work in correspondence with the unknown number or list items. Do you mean something along the lines of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489946/how-to-wait-for-the-end-of-resize-event-and-only-then-perform-an-action

Comment: I think still I haven't got your question. Will be helpfull if you explain with example or codepen link. May be I can help you with better solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use JS:
1) Make an event listener that will react everytime you resize the browser like:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){

});
```

2) Create a function that will be fired every time user resizes the window

```
function handleResize(){

}
```

3) Call that function in your eventListener like so :

```
 window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
      handleResize();
    });
```

4) create a variable that will store the list of your list items like:

```
  const items = document.querySelectorAll(".some-list");
```

5) get the width of the screen -> https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_screen.asp

5) inside your handleResize function - check the width of the screen and based on that + based on the numbers of the elements - add a particular css class like

```
.visible {
dsiplay:block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I this is a solution to my question :)

Comment: Great to hear that :) Good luck !