# Push the content behind the fixed position header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created fiddle regarding the problem issue in [link here](https://jsfiddle.net/d0pyxdoj/2/W)

Header and footer are absolutely positioned and 100% width. The middle content consists of the dashboard table. Header consists of two images, which on clicked, will toggle the content.
When I click on `slide-toggle-1`, the content of `headerbottombar` is revealed.
But the  middle content is hidden and overlapped.
How can I properly show content of middle content when the `slide-button-1` and `slide-button-2` is clicked.
I would  like to thank for all suggestions and solutions. Solutions are acceptable either in ***css, jquery and javascript*** as long as feasible solutions are presented.

Comment: Explain more  about your problem . i saw your code and it worked properly  .  when toggle opened the content of behind must be hidden . what do you want to do ?

Comment: When the toggle is opened, I want the  div class content to  follow behind the header. In my case, the div class content is laying behind the header.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/d0pyxdoj/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you try adding a class with margin-top to bring the div down as much as needed. Like this:

`.top{
  margin-top:100px;
}`

Add this to you div with ".content" Like so:

`<div class="content top">`

Then just toggle it on the 2 clicks like:

`$( ".content" ).toggleClass( "top" );`

You can give additional styles, but this is the basic run down.

Comment: can i have fiddle please

Answer (score 0):

**Update :** 
If you want a variable height header that's sticky to the top, you might have to use some javascript that dynamically adjusts the top margin of the content

```
var offset = document.getElementById("sticky-top-id").offsetHeight;
document.getElementById("content-id").style.marginTop = offset + 'px';
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414384/how-do-i-use-css-to-position-a-fixed-variable-height-header-and-a-scrollable-con)

**Old Answer :**

There are many ways to achieve what you want. One is to change the position of header to `relative` (and remove the line breaks between header and content). If you use `fixed` or `absolute` position, the header will overlap with the body content. Whereas relative will push the content down as the header expands.

See this : https://jsfiddle.net/d0pyxdoj/3/

P.S. Header/Footer have position `fixed` in your code, not `absolute`

Comment: In my case, it is clients demand that header be alwasy visible and stick to top as well

Comment: So I used header fixed positioning

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below example. Height identification using script we can inject the spacing.

**Script:**

```
function heightCalc(){
         topHeight = $('.sticky-top').height();
       $('.content').css({"margin-top": topHeight+"px"});
     }
```

**Example Fiddler :** https://jsfiddle.net/scj4u0t5/1/