# .wrap() is adding the selector multiple times when used with resize function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm using a resize function to wrap a `div` with a container when the browser width is less than `801px` or the height is greater than the width. My problem is when either of those become true then the `div` gets wrapped with the selector 8 times. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 function wrapperWidth() {
  var wrapper_width = $('body').width();
   if (wrapper_width < 801 || window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth) {
      $('.video-profile').wrap("<div></div>");
   }
 }
 wrapperWidth();
 $(window).resize(function() {
wrapperWidth();
 });
});
```

When the the browser width becomes less than 801px I get this.

```
<div>
 <div>
  <div>
   <div>
    <div>
     <div>
      <div>
       <div>
        <div class="video-profile"></div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Presumably it's wrapping with divs until the width becomes greater than 801px.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browsers can fire the resize event multiple times during a resize operation, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658517/window-resize-in-jquery-firing-multiple-times) for more details.

I suggest checking for presence of the container to avoid duplicates:

```
if (wrapper_width < 801 || window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth) {
    if (!$('.video-profile').parent().hasClass('vp-container')) {
        $('.video-profile').wrap("<div class="vp-container"></div>");
    }
}
```