# proportional to the width of the window to change the width of the div with jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I changed the width of the browser you want to change in proportion to the width of an image in the content.

For example, at first;

```
Browser Width: 1600 px | Height: 800 px
Image Width: 1024 px | Height: 660 px
```

After the time has changed;

```
Browser width: 1200px | height: 600px
image width: 600px | height: 400px such as ..
```

This is how we will establish the proportions I could not ..
Waiting for your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why don't you use % instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to resize the image whilst maintaining the same aspect ratio, don't set a width AND height. Only adjust one.

CSS solution:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1600px) {
    img {
        width: 1024px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    img {
        width: 600px;
    }
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W6XzK/1/)

---

jQuery solution:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var theWidth = $(window).width();

    if (theWidth >= 1600) {
        $(img).css('width','1024px');
    } else if (theWidth < 1200) {
        $(img).css('width','600px');
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R2Rq4/)

Resize tends to fire multiple times in some browsers so if you want to use jQuery you might want to try a solution like this: [window.resize in jquery firing multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658517/window-resize-in-jquery-firing-multiple-times)

Answer (score 0):

Just use a percentage [`width`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-width-property) and [`height`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-height-property)

HTML:

```
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/1024/600"/>
```

CSS:

```
img {
    width: 65%;
    height: 80%;
}
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K5ckf/)