# jQuery on re-sizeing back

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, window-resize

I have this code which allows me to change the style sheet when the browser is re-sized:

```
            $(window).resize(function () {
            var width = $(window).width();
            var height = $(window).height();

            if ((width <= 1280) && (height <= 800)) {
                $("link[rel=stylesheet]:not(:first)").attr({ href: "Styles/Home-1024.css" });
            }
            else if ((width > 1280) && (height > 800)) {
                $("link[rel=stylesheet]:not(:first)").attr({ href: "Styles/Home.css" });
            }
        });
```

and it works fine but i am trying to change the style sheet again when the browser returns to its original size.

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem. If your code works, won't it fire both when the browser is resized the first time, *and* when the browser is size back to its original size?

Comment: @Joshua Moore - that's what i thought but it only works on the first resize and never on the second one

Comment: Can you set up an example at jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @Joshua Moore - [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QpnxC/2/) is an example its different that this since i cant add style sheets on jsfiddle

Comment: You should remove the solution from your question and add it as an answer (and accept it if it actually solved your problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was missing a double greater than so instead of this :

```
else if ((width > 1280) && (height > 800)) {
```

i used this and it worked:

```
else if ((width >> 1280) && (height >> 800)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$(window).live("resize", function(){

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think part of the problem is that the script fires at each moment of each drag.

You might consider adding a delay so that the event is not repeated so many times.

See this: [JavaScript/JQuery: $(window).resize how to fire AFTER the resize is completed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854407/javascript-jquery-window-resize-how-to-fire-after-the-resize-is-completed)

Comment: tried it and it activates with a delay but again it only fires on the first resize but not after that

Comment: One issue I see with this approach: If the delay is too long, the page might change (depending on the difference in stylesheets, drastically) and look jerky.

Comment: would you recommend a different approach