# Updating Canvas on Window Resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, filter

I'm new to working with canvas elements and am attempting to draw a full screen image, then do some pixel modification. I've written a small method for this and loading the image works perfectly, but resizing the browser window is dreadfully slow - even with a throttler.

Here's my method for drawing an image to the canvas, and apply an image filter effect to it:

```
drawCanvas:function(obj,src,onResize){
   var img=new Image(), 
       objData=$.data(obj), 
       canvas=Plugin.OBJ.$Canvas[0], 
       ctx=canvas.getContext("2d"), 
       win=$(window), 
       winW=win.width(), 
       winH=win.height();       

    img.src=src; 
    Plugin.CanvasSRC=src;

    img.onload=function(){ 
    var imgW=img.width, 
            imgH=img.height, 
            ratio=imgW/imgH;
        newH=(Math.round(winW/ratio)<winH)?winH:Math.round(winW/ratio), 
            winW=(newH<winH)?$win.width():Math.round(newH*ratio);

        canvas.width=winW; canvas.height=newH;
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,winW,newH);

    var imgdata=ctx.getImageData(0,0,winW,winH), 
            pix=imgdata.data, 
            l=pix.length, 
            filter=objData.bg_pic_filter;

    switch(filter){ ... this section does the pixel manipulation ...};

    // APPLY THE FILTER && FADE IN 
    ctx.putImageData(imgdata,0,0);
    };
},
```

Hopefully I'm not too incredibly off from this, but I'm wondering if there's a better way to simply draw an image to a full-screen canvas, but have it maintain its dimensions similar to background-size:cover? These images are using pixel manipulation filters as well. Is it possible to just size the canvas on window resize without having to redraw it and reapply the filter every time? 
Thanks!

Comment: maybe you can have an off screen canvas of a fixed size where you would do all your calculations, and then have another one on screen, and just copy image from the first one on resize? or even generate an image from the first canvas and just show it? the idea is to cache the results of the calculation and not redo the work on every resize.

Comment: Thanks :) How would I go about doing that?

Comment: I would use `document.createElement("canvas")`. Just do not attach it to DOM.

Comment: here is a good example of caching using canvas: https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/blob/master/src/easeljs/display/DisplayObject.js#L647

Comment: @akonsu: +1 for buffering on a separate canvas.

Answer (score 1):

**Some thoughts about your question:**

When you say “even with a throttler” I’m assuming you are keeping your expensive redraw from being triggered repeatedly.  Something like this:  [JavaScript/JQuery: $(window).resize how to fire AFTER the resize is completed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854407/javascript-jquery-window-resize-how-to-fire-after-the-resize-is-completed)

```
// on resizing, call for a delay
// after the delay call your drawCanvas()
$(window).resize(function () {
    waitForFinalEvent(function(){ drawCanvas(); }, 500, randomID());
});

// wait for the specified delay time before doing callback
// if this is called again before timeout, restart the timer
var waitForFinalEvent = (function () {
  var timers = {};
  return function (callback, ms, uniqueId) {
    if (timers[uniqueId]) {
      clearTimeout (timers[uniqueId]);
    }
    timers[uniqueId] = setTimeout(callback, ms);
  };
})();

// generate a "good enough" unique id
function randomID() {
   return (((1+Math.random())*0x10000)|0).toString(16).substring(1);
}
```

If your original filtered image will survive a resizing without unacceptable pixelating, you can save the original image to a dataURL and then just scale+redraw that saved image on your resized canvas like this:

```
// save the canvas content as imageURL
var data=canvas.toDataURL();

// resize the canvas
canvas.width*=scaleFactor;
canvas.height*=scaleFactor;

// scale and redraw the canvas content
var img=new Image();
img.onload=function(){
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,img.width,img.height,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
}
img.src=data;
```