# How do I stop onResize function executing its contents while resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want the content of `jQuery.fn.resize` to only execute after i let go of the mouse button not while i am resizing the window.

I have tried putting onmousedown inside on resize but it didn't work.

```
$(window).resize(function(){           
    console.log("resizing")
});
```

Comment: If you want it log after resize then you should listen to onmouseup instead.

Comment: @SubirKumarSao not every resize event is followed by an `mouseup` event.

Comment: Most solutions talk about time delays. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854407/javascript-jquery-window-resize-how-to-fire-after-the-resize-is-completed

Comment: Look into the [jQuery throttle/debounce](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) plugin. Scroll handling is one of their examples.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14092859/1250044

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't know what happens outside your document, and you're not notified when the resizing ends (a resizing can occur in many ways, not all of them mouse based).

But you could add a timer for the same effect :

```
(function(){
   var timer;
   $(window).resize(function(){
        if (timer) clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function(){
           // do the things
        }, 200);
   });
})();
```

This would add a slight delay (200 ms should be ok) but this would avoid most intermediate recomputing.

Note that you don't receive events when your javascript function is running, so you usually don't have to do this unless you really want the user to not see anything during the resizing.

Comment: @yckart What he asked isn't possible. This is what should be the nearest for the user while being possible.

Comment: Yeah, that's true! But it was not clear before your editing. ;)