# Resize event is called multiple times

Tags: jquery

It's called repeatedly only when you grab the left/right border of the browser and start moving, so it removes and inserts the `#video` really fast, making it really annoying.

Is there a way to trigger the "remove-insert" sequence only if the width limit is reached?

```
if($(window).width() <= 820) {
    $("#video").remove().insertBefore("#slideshow");
} 

if($(window).width() >= 820) {
    $("#video").remove().insertAfter("#slideshow");
}
```

Comment: If at all possible, I'd explore a CSS/media-queries approach to this before resorting to JS. Stripping out and reinserting DOM elements in response to dimension changes, though perhaps sometimes required as a last resort, is inelegant.

Comment: Why not use a proper media query? Barring that, store the previous iteration's width and only fire if you've crossed the threshold.

Comment: if you're moving the video, there's no need to remove it, just move it.

Comment: That's how resize works.  What you want is to "debounce" (or throttle) it.  This should help: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript/JQuery: $(window).resize how to fire AFTER the resize is completed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854407/javascript-jquery-window-resize-how-to-fire-after-the-resize-is-completed)

Answer (score 1):

Keep track of the video’s previous position:

```
var wasAfter = true; // Or wherever it starts

function moveVideo() {
    var width = $(window).width();
    var video = $('#video');
    var slideshow = $('#slideshow');

    if(width < 820) {
        if(wasAfter) {
            video.insertBefore(slideshow);
            wasAfter = false;
        }
    } else if(!wasAfter) {
        video.insertAfter(slideshow);
        wasAfter = true;
    }
}
```