# fire a function after window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, resize

I'm doing a few functions on `$(window).resize()`. One of the functions inside it, is a complex animation with lots of divs.

```
$window.resize(function() {
    // some functions
    doAnim();
}
```

the problem here is, that the `resize()` function triggers a lot. Is it possible to fire one function after the `resize()` is finished, that it doesnt fire a hundred times?

Cheers

Comment: you mean you want to fire a function only one time ?

Comment: @SpiderCode yes but after the resize is finished, so that after the mouse is released!

Comment: This has been asked numerous times before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854407/javascript-jquery-window-resize-how-to-fire-after-the-resize-is-completed

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298612/jquery-how-to-call-resize-event-only-once-its-finished-resizing

Comment: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/

Comment: http://underscorejs.org/#throttle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I believe this is a similar scenario when a user "type" something: you can't know when the user finished to compose a sentence, the same here, you don't know when the user has finished to resize; so what you can do is have an acceptable interval:

```
var idt;
$(window).resize(function() {
    if (idt) clearTimeout(idt);
    idt = setTimeout(doAnim, 500);
}
```

You can also use a closure to avoid to pollute the global scope with `idt` variable.

However the main point here is that every time the user resize the window, it set a timeout and clear the previous one: the `doAnim` function will be executed only if the user leave the window without resizing it for half second. Of course you can set your own delay.

Comment: yep, thats it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it as shown below. This will call when you finish with resizing :

```
        var myTimer;
        $(window).resize(function() 
        {
            // some functions
            var interval = 500;
            clearInterval(myTimer);
            myTimer = setInterval(function () { doAnim(); }, interval);
        });

        function doAnim() 
        {
            clearInterval(myTimer);
            alert('Resized');
        }
```