# Javascript on window resize end

Tags: javascript, resize, window

I am calling a function when the window is resized like this:

```
window.addEventListener("resize", calculateDimensions());
```

But I need a way to call a different function AFTER the window has been resized.
Is there any way to achieve this using native js (not jquery)

TIA

Comment: You may wanna pass a function and not the result of a function?

Comment: Use `window.addEventListener("resize", calculateDimensions);` `calculateDimensions()` means that you execute the function and then use that result as a callback function.

Comment: Check [this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19835604/fire-a-function-after-window-resize)

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5489946

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You could set a Timeout and reset it when resize is fired again. So the last timeout isnt canceled and the function is run:

```
function debounce(func){
  var timer;
  return function(event){
    if(timer) clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(func,100,event);
  };
}
```

Usable like this:

```
window.addEventListener("resize",debounce(function(e){
  alert("end of resizing");
}));
```

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, but I want to call the calculateDimensions as the window resizes, and a different function once the resize has ended, how would I use your great example to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: @ronny vdb you already have a calculate dimensions listener. Add the upper code, Put that other function instead of the alert above and youre done...

Comment: I know, the op already has his answer, but for future references, I would like to add a code pen - https://codepen.io/dcorb/pen/XXPjpd
Source - https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/

Answer (score 19):

I like [Jonas Wilms](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5260024/jonas-wilms) nifty little debounce function, however I think it would be nicer to pass the debounce time as a param.

```
// Debounce
function debounce(func, time){
    var time = time || 100; // 100 by default if no param
    var timer;
    return function(event){
        if(timer) clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(func, time, event);
    };
}

// Function with stuff to execute
function resizeContent() {
    // Do loads of stuff once window has resized
    console.log('resized');
}

// Eventlistener
window.addEventListener("resize", debounce( resizeContent, 150 ));
```

Comment: Agreed, and those first two lines could be rewritten as `function debounce(func, time = 100){`.

Answer (score 0):

Using npm `debounce` package:

```sh
npm i debounce
```

```js
const debounce = require('debounce');
window.onresize = debounce(resize, 200);

function resize(e) {
  console.log('height', window.innerHeight);
  console.log('width', window.innerWidth);
}
```