# jQuery resize once

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
jQuery( window ).resize(function(){
  if ( jQuery( window ).width() < 1199 && jQuery( window ).width() > 991 ) {
     jQuery("body").load(location.href);
     image_scale_height();
     ctitle_scale_height();
  }
});
```

I wanted to read the code under that range only ONCE but when I resize it within that range, it act like a loop, it always read all within that range.

Comment: @ChrisG not going to work for what OP wants....

Comment: So add a boolean if it was loaded or not.

Comment: You could just fire the event after the [resizing ends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45905160/javascript-on-window-resize-end) - if you only fire it once, then what happens when your event is done for the wrong screen size and the user continues to resize

Comment: you could check this solution to that issue: https://alvarotrigo.com/blog/firing-resize-event-only-once-when-resizing-is-finished/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `.load()` function for the reason every load of the page it will reset the 
value of `reached` variable.

```
var reached = false;

jQuery( window ).resize(function(){
  if ( jQuery( window ).width() < 1199 && jQuery( window ).width() > 991 ) {
     if( !reached ){
        jQuery("body").load(location.href);
        image_scale_height();
        ctitle_scale_height();
        reached = true;
     }
  }else{
    reached = false;
  }
});
```

instead, for the `image_scale_height();` and `ctitle_scale_height();` you can just simply reset the height at the css.

You can do this:

**CSS**

```
@media (max-width: 1199px) and (min-width: 991px){
  division{
     heigth: auto;
}
```

**Java Script**

```
jQuery( window ).resize(function(){
  if ( jQuery( window ).width() < 1199 && jQuery( window ).width() > 991 ) {
     image_scale_height();
     ctitle_scale_height();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/rbespj61/1/)**.

You could use a flag variable for this, the flag (`reached` in my suggestion) 
 is `false` by default will be `true` if the condition was reached and when the user resizes out of the range it will be `false` again that will prevent the redundant, like :

```
var reached = false;

jQuery( window ).resize(function(){
  if ( jQuery( window ).width() < 1199 && jQuery( window ).width() > 991 ) {
     if( !reached ){
        console.log( 'My action' , reached );
        reached = true;
     }
  }else{
    reached = false;
  }
});
```

**Note:** If you want your action to be executed just one time you have just to remove the `else` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Just track it like this:

```
var resized = false;

jQuery(window).resize(function() {
  if (jQuery(window).width() < 1199 && jQuery(window).width() > 991) {
    if (resized) return; // don't do it twice
    jQuery("body").load(location.href);
    image_scale_height();
    ctitle_scale_height();
    resized = true;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use `.one()` or `.off()`.
http://api.jquery.com/off/
http://api.jquery.com/one/

For `.one()`, change function to this -

```
jQuery( window ).one("resize", function(){ 
  if( jQuery( window ).width() < 1199 && jQuery( window ).width() > 991 ) { 
     jQuery("body").load(location.href); image_scale_height(); ctitle_scale_height(); 
} 
});
```

But if window is resized once even outside the range, it won't execute again. So I would advise using `.off()` -

```
jQuery( window ).resize( function(){ 
  if( jQuery( window ).width() < 1199 && jQuery( window ).width() > 991 ) { 
     jQuery("body").load(location.href); image_scale_height(); ctitle_scale_height(); 
jQuery(window).off("resize");
} 
});
```

This will remove **all** resize handlers from window set by jQuery.