# Window resize causes animation to accelerate. (ThreeJS)

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have the following code and I'm wondering why it speeds out of control when I resize the window.

```html
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        
        <h1>FooBarBaz</h1>
        <p>LaDeDa</p>
        <script src="http://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js"></script>
        <script>
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
        
        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        
        var objects = [
            {
                name : "earth",
                mesh : new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 32, 32), new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial()),
                init : function(scene){
                this.mesh.position.set(0,0,0);
                //this.material.map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('../earth.jpg');
                scene.add(this.mesh);
                },
                animate : function(t){return}
            },
            {
                name : "satellite",
                mesh : new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.1, 32, 32), new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial()),
                init : function(scene){
                this.mesh.position.set(1.5,0,0);
                //this.material.map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('../earth.jpg');
                scene.add(this.mesh);
                },
                animate : function(t){this.mesh.position.set(Math.sin(t)*1.5,Math.cos(t)*1.5,0);}
            }];
        objects.forEach(object => object.init(scene));
        
        var light = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xf6e86d, 0x404040, 0.5);
        scene.add(light);
        
        camera.position.x = 0;
        camera.position.y = -5;
        camera.position.z = 0;
        camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0));
        var timeStep = 0.01;
        var time = 0;
        var controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
        controls.target.set( 0, 0, 0 );
        var render = function () {
            time += timeStep;
            requestAnimationFrame( render );
            objects.forEach(object => object.animate(time));
            controls.update();
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }
        function onWindowResize() {
            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix()
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
            render()
        }
        window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false)
        
        document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
        render();</script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

As you can see every time you resize the window it starts going faster and faster... Why?

Comment: Do you realize that `resize` fires multiple times? So you are calling your render code a lot of times.

Comment: Yeah I get that, but even after resizing the animation continues to be accelerated...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45905160/javascript-on-window-resize-end

Comment: Well you are calling `time += timeStep;`  so it will keep on increasing and you are calling that animate code a lot.

Comment: yeah but why is time increasing faster after resizing the window? I get that it increases faster while resizing the window but when the window is fixed shouldn't the rate of change for time be fairly consistent?

Comment: Just use the debounce code and verify it gets fixed.

Comment: No that's not it. I figured it out. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because resize calls render and render calls request animation frame(render) you end up with multiple reclusive loops of render overlapping. By adding a function renderOnce that doesn't request animation frame and using that for resizing the problem is solved. The animation will still move slightly faster while resizing but once resizing is complete the animation speed is back to normal.

```
    var renderOnce = function () {
        time += timeStep;
        objects.forEach(object => object.animate(time));
        controls.update();
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
    var render = function () {
        renderOnce();
        requestAnimationFrame( render );
    }
    window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false)
    function onWindowResize() {
        camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        renderOnce();
    }
```

Also the acceleration while resizing can be solved by moving time+=timeStep from renderOnce to render.

Comment: The [resize event](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-loop-processing-model:run-the-resize-steps) is tied to animation frames anyway, no need to call render at all from there.