# jQuery $(window).resize(); equivalent event listener, that only fires on a specified axis change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

I am looking for an event listener, what works like jQuery's `.resize()`, but only fires when the resized object (talking about the window) is resized in x axis, or both, but not in only y axis. - So basically it will only listen the resize events of the width.

Comment: This page is can answer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854407/javascript-jquery-window-resize-how-to-fire-after-the-resize-is-completed.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can save the width of the browser on a window load in variable. Example:

```
var w = 0;

$( window ).load( function(){

   w = $( window ).width();

});

$( window ).resize( function(){

  if( w != $( window ).width() ){

    //Do something

    w = $( window ).width();


  }

});
```

Comment: If I might add - this might not be reliable over a longer period of time, as garbage collection could/would remove the variable if it is no longer referenced...if someone could answer this it would be most appreciated as I have experienced issues regarding exactly this in the past...

Answer (score 5):

How about using like this?

```
var w = $(window).width();
$(window).resize(function(){
  if ($(window).width()==w) return; 
  w = $(window).width();
  // ... your code
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$(window).resize(function(e) {
console.log(e.old.width + " - " + $(this).width());
console.log(e.old.height + " - " + $(this).height());
if(e.old.width==$(this).width() && e.old.height!=$(this).height()){
//only vertical resize done
}else
{
 //horizontal or horizontal+ vertical resize done
}
});​
```