# collapsing bxslider when element style"display:none"

Tags: jquery-ui, displaytag, bxslider

I would like to use [bxslider](http://bxslider.com/) for a project.

But there is the problem connected with using more than one slider at the same page (three in my example).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.slider1').bxSlider({
        slideWidth: 200,
        minSlides: 2,
        maxSlides: 3,
        slideMargin: 10
    });
    $('.slider2').bxSlider({
        slideWidth: 200,
        minSlides: 2,
        maxSlides: 3,
        slideMargin: 10
    });
    $('.slider3').bxSlider({
        slideWidth: 200,
        minSlides: 2,
        maxSlides: 3,
        slideMargin: 10
    });
});
```

I have made the example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FvMYz/2272/)

If you select in my example **Option 2** or **Option 3** you will see that slider collapses.

As I see it the problem is `style="display:none"` in `div` for **Option 2** and **Option 3**.

Can anybody help to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I agree. It seems to be related to display:none. 
Here is how you get past the collapsed spinner....

First, you have to assign each slider to a variable when you create it. Make these global because you will need them later.

```
sldr1 = $('.slider1').bxSlider({
            slideWidth: 200,
            minSlides: 2,
            maxSlides: 3,
            slideMargin: 10
        });
```

when you show the new spinner, you have to use

```
 sldr1.reloadSlider();
```

A hallmark of my problem, which your jsfiddle shares, is that I can re-size the window and the collapsed spinner will display properly. I spent a lot of time trying to re-size $(window) or $(document) to get the spinner to react, I failed to find something that would work.

For the benefit of any poor souls who are co-afflicted with this challenge, the important thing to note is that you have to store a reference at init time.

you can not do this in your selection function...

```
//hide and show logic
.
.
.
//reload slider
sldr1 = $('.slider1').bxSlider();
sldr1.reloadSlider();
```

Although this seems like it might work, bxSlider() can not be used to simply get a reference to an existing spinner. It actually creates a second slider. If you do this you will notice multiple controls, etc.
A careful re-reading of the documentation shows that this is by design. So not a bug, just a learning thing. Fine. The gentleman contributed his work, so I'll happily take it as it lies.

My one other tip: i was getting white padding on the left of the slides. That was the LI bullets manifesting themselves. Something to do w/ my complicated CSS not playing nice w/ bxslider CSS. I changed to DIV slides inside a DIV container. BxSlider works well with this as per documentation.

good luck