# How to check if browser window is fully resized or not?

Tags: javascript, browser, dom-events, window-resize

I want to execute one function, after my window is fully resized.

```
window.resizeTo('792','115');

myFunction();
```

**My question :**

1.Does the `myFunction()` method will be called only after the window is fully resized ?

2.If yes mean no problem for me, else I want the below scenario ?

**My need :**

I need a pure Javascript solution.

```
if(windowIsFullyResized){
      myFunction();
}else{
      // wait for window resize and again call myFunction();
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Like it says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12692647/2593518), you can do this :

I prefer to create an event:

```
$(window).bind('resizeEnd', function() {
    //do something, window hasn't changed size in 500ms
});
```

Here is how you create it:

```
 $(window).resize(function() {
        if(this.resizeTO) clearTimeout(this.resizeTO);
        this.resizeTO = setTimeout(function() {
            $(this).trigger('resizeEnd');
        }, 500);
    });
```

You could have this in a global javascript file somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I need a pure javascript solution.

Comment: You are debouncing event, not bad!

Comment: @HumanBeing You are lucky, jQuery is a javascript library, so not that hard to 'convert' code/syntax. And funny enough you had tagged question with jQuery tag...

Comment: @Wolf In my project we can't include or use the jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this maybe:

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    if(windowWidth == 792 && windowHeight == 115) myFUnction();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I need a pure javascript solution.

Comment: I have to do the same thing , only after my window is resized .

Comment: `window.onresize=function(){SomeJavaScriptCode};`

Comment: In some case , it fails. So only I am asking how to check , browser window is fully resized or not?