# When reaching viewport point then troggle my sidebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, viewport

I need to be able to troggle my sidebar.
This works but I also need to hide the sidebar when reach viewport > 740px.
The troggle needs to work also. I came a far way but I think I have to combine these two to let it work properly.

Anyone knows hot to do this?

[CHECK OUT MY FIDDLE PLEASE >](http://jsfiddle.net/fourroses666/wXbRf/2/)

**My script:**

```
$('.troggler').toggle(
    function() {
        $('.right').animate({"right": "-400px"}, "slow");
        $('.troggler').animate({"background-position": "-25px"}, "fast");
    }, function() {
        $('.right').animate({"right": "0"}, "slow");
        $('.troggler').animate({"background-position": "0"}, "fast");
})

$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 740) {
        $(".right").animate({"right": "-400px"}, "slow");
        $('.troggler').animate({"background-position": "-25px"}, "fast");
    }
    else {
        $('.right').animate({"right": "0"}, "slow");
        $('.troggler').animate({"background-position": "0"}, "fast");
    }
});
```

Comment: wouldn't recommend using that toggle method since it is deprecated  http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/ Is valid in 1.7 as in demo but if you upgrade can cause issues

Comment: I'm open for any improvement although I'm not planning to update the js version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the `$(window).resize()` fires multiple events  while you ara resizing the window.
To solve this, you might wait for the resizing (dragging) complete.

```
// Basic Concept is ...
$(window).resize(function () {

    if( ... event not fired ...  ){
       setTimeout(function(){
            // toggle your navi
       },500);
    }
    ....
});
```

DEMO:http://jsfiddle.net/VseLR/13/

Your code could go like this:

```
function showNavi(){
    $('.right').animate({"right": "0"}, "slow");
    $('.troggler').animate({"background-position": "0"}, "fast");
}
function hideNavi(){
    $('.right').animate({"right": "-400px"}, "slow");
    $('.troggler').animate({"background-position": "-25px"}, "fast");
}

$('.troggler').toggle(function() {
        showNavi();},
    function() {
        hideNavi();
    });

function applyLayout() {
    if ($(window).width() < 740) {
       hideNavi();
    }else {
       showNavi();
    }
}
var timer = 0;
var delayToCall = (function () {
    return function (callback, ms) {
        if (timer > 0) {
            clearTimeout (timer);
        }
        timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
    };
})();
$(window).resize(function () {
   delayToCall(function(){
     applyLayout();
    }, 500);
});
```

You might want to check this question:
[JavaScript/JQuery: $(window).resize how to fire AFTER the resize is completed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854407/javascript-jquery-window-resize-how-to-fire-after-the-resize-is-completed)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks allot naota! there is one thing: when having large viewport and click on close, nothing happens, click again and then it works. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: @fourroses, Yes. I guess it's because the first parameter of `.toggle()` is show  and 2nd parameter is hide. You might want to change order to opposite like this: http://jsfiddle.net/VseLR/15/