# While resize browser window counter variable value should be incremented by 1 value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing a problem whenever I resize the browser window by (CTRL+SHFT+M) or change the orientation of window. `counter_` variable value increament by 4 or 7 instead of 1.

HTML:

```
<div id="my_element">
    <span id="text">0</span> window resize.
</div>
```

Script:

```
$(function () {
    var counter_ = 0;
    $(window).on('resize', function () {
        $('#text').text(++counter_);
    });
});
```

Output Should be:

> 0 window resize.
>
> 1 window resize.
>
> 2 window resize.
>
> ..
>
> ..

Comment: The `resize()` event is called once for every pixel the window is changed by. You may need to use a timer to debounce the effect if you only want to count an entire resize as one operation.

Comment: [JavaScript/JQuery: $(window).resize how to fire AFTER the resize is completed?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2854407/387194)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan not for every pixel, for every repaint. If your browser decides to not repaint the page during resize, you might end up with one resize event only. OTOH, you can easily get multiple resize events for the same window size.

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
$('#my_element').append('<span class="text">' + (counter_++) + '</span> window resize.');
```

As in this [**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/406/)

Comment: @JohnHascall how they can disappear?

Comment: The person who created them deletes it.

Comment: @JohnHascall This fiddle is anonymous it can't be deleted.

Comment: Also JSFiddle interface don't have delete option.

Comment: Ok, points taken.  But there is no guaranty that jsfiddle itself exists at all next year, next week, or even tomorrow.  That, in general, not just for jsfiddle, is the reason that putting the answer in the answer and not off at some other site is preferred.

Comment: @JohnHascall but it's better to include example that work instead of the one that don't, like with stack snipets that have resize event.