# What is an alternative to 'resize' on mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I am trying to trigger an event in a web browser on a desktop

```
$(window).trigger('resize');
```

The issue is on mobile it doesn't seem to be triggering. Is there an alternative method for mobile?

I am using tablesaw plugin for grids. When the screen is small in size, the columns will not fit and as such a swipe will be provided to move between them. When I sort them, all the columns gets squeezed and shown on the small screen, but after I trigger the resize event, an event in the plugin will get called that will fix them. On the mobile, this event doesn't exist I guess and I'm not targeting the orientation.

Comment: Resize on mobile?  What are you trying to do?  Are you looking for the `onOrientationChange` event?

Comment: This might be informative: [The Resize Event on Mobile](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/resize_mobile.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a variation of this ([JavaScript/JQuery: $(window).resize how to fire AFTER the resize is completed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854407/javascript-jquery-window-resize-how-to-fire-after-the-resize-is-completed/4541963#4541963))

this will run on resize and orientchange.

```
var waitForFinalEvent=function(){var b={};return function(c,d,a){a||(a="THISPAGE");b[a]&&clearTimeout(b[a]);b[a]=setTimeout(c,d)}}();
var fullDateString = new Date();

$(document).ready(function(){

   $.resized = function(){

    waitForFinalEvent(function(){
        //function to run

       }, 300, fullDateString.getTime())
    }

    window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
        $.resized();
    });

    $(window).resize(function () {
        $.resized();
    });

    $.resized();

    });
```

Comment: I can't access the method in the plugin... It's written in a way that it is private.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation and maybe links to docs? Just code without any explanation isn't very useful -- it may help the OP, but probably won't help future visitors.