# Reload window on resize browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to reload the page on browser resize only, I tried the following code it's loading the browser again and again however I am not resizing the browser window.

```
$(window).on('resize',function(){
    location.reload();
});
```

also i tried this code with `$(document).ready(function() { });` but not working

Comment: I think you have opened your console. Please close your console and try once again

Comment: My guess is that the browser is resizing because of the content on the page, specifically when the scroll bar is added after the content becomes too long. Is your JavaScript is at the end of your body so that it loads last?

Comment: I would also suggest implementing this so that you don't make your users want to leave: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854407/javascript-jquery-window-resize-how-to-fire-after-the-resize-is-completed?rq=1

Comment: _“I want to reload the page on browser resize only”_ – that sounds like a really really rehaheally bad idea. _Why_ do you want to do that?

Comment: i am giving equal height to my elements which changes when browser resize so i want to reload my page when user expand or reduce the window size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this..

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function () { 
    "use strict";
    window.location.reload(); 
});
```

Comment: it helped me 50% my code is `window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
    "use strict";
     window.location.href = window.location.href;
});`

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct. Check if you are triggering the resize event programmatically somewhere in your code like `$(window).trigger('resize');`. Also if keep in mind that if you have your inspector open and you expand it, that also triggers the window resize event.